# How to test the membership of multiple values in a list

Tags: python

I want to test if two or more values have membership on a list, but I'm getting an unexpected result:

```
>>> 'a','b' in ['b', 'a', 'foo', 'bar']
('a', True)
```

So, Can Python test the membership of multiple values at once in a list?
What does that result mean?

---

<sub>See also: [How to find list intersection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432). Checking whether *any* of the specified values is in the list, is equivalent to checking if the intersection is non-empty. Checking whether *all* the values are in the list, is equivalent to checking if they are a subset.</sub>

Answer (score 298, accepted):

This does what you want, and will work in nearly all cases:

```
>>> all(x in ['b', 'a', 'foo', 'bar'] for x in ['a', 'b'])
True
```

The expression `'a','b' in ['b', 'a', 'foo', 'bar']` doesn't work as expected because Python interprets it as a tuple:

```
>>> 'a', 'b'
('a', 'b')
>>> 'a', 5 + 2
('a', 7)
>>> 'a', 'x' in 'xerxes'
('a', True)
```

#### Other Options

There are other ways to execute this test, but they won't work for as many different kinds of inputs. As [Kabie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6159356/577088) points out, you can solve this problem using sets...

```
>>> set(['a', 'b']).issubset(set(['a', 'b', 'foo', 'bar']))
True
>>> {'a', 'b'} <= {'a', 'b', 'foo', 'bar'}
True
```

...sometimes:

```
>>> {'a', ['b']} <= {'a', ['b'], 'foo', 'bar'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Sets can only be created with hashable elements. But the generator expression `all(x in container for x in items)` can handle almost any container type. The only requirement is that `container` be re-iterable (i.e. not a generator). `items` can be any iterable at all.

```
>>> container = [['b'], 'a', 'foo', 'bar']
>>> items = (i for i in ('a', ['b']))
>>> all(x in [['b'], 'a', 'foo', 'bar'] for x in items)
True
```

#### Speed Tests

In many cases, the subset test will be faster than `all`, but the difference isn't shocking -- except when the question is irrelevant because sets aren't an option. Converting lists to sets just for the purpose of a test like this won't always be worth the trouble. And converting generators to sets can sometimes be incredibly wasteful, slowing programs down by many orders of magnitude.

Here are a few benchmarks for illustration. The biggest difference comes when both `container` and `items` are relatively small. In that case, the subset approach is about an order of magnitude faster:

```
>>> smallset = set(range(10))
>>> smallsubset = set(range(5))
>>> %timeit smallset >= smallsubset
110 ns ± 0.702 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
>>> %timeit all(x in smallset for x in smallsubset)
951 ns ± 11.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

This looks like a big difference. But as long as `container` is a set, `all` is still perfectly usable at vastly larger scales:

```
>>> bigset = set(range(100000))
>>> bigsubset = set(range(50000))
>>> %timeit bigset >= bigsubset
1.14 ms ± 13.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
>>> %timeit all(x in bigset for x in bigsubset)
5.96 ms ± 37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Using subset testing is still faster, but only by about 5x at this scale. The speed boost is due to Python's fast `c`-backed implementation of `set`, but the fundamental algorithm is the same in both cases.

If your `items` are already stored in a list for other reasons, then you'll have to convert them to a set before using the subset test approach. Then the speedup drops to about 2.5x:

```
>>> %timeit bigset >= set(bigsubseq)
2.1 ms ± 49.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

And if your `container` is a sequence, and needs to be converted first, then the speedup is even smaller:

```
>>> %timeit set(bigseq) >= set(bigsubseq)
4.36 ms ± 31.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The only time we get disastrously slow results is when we leave `container` as a sequence:

```
>>> %timeit all(x in bigseq for x in bigsubseq)
184 ms ± 994 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

And of course, we'll only do that if we must. If all the items in `bigseq` are hashable, then we'll do this instead:

```
>>> %timeit bigset = set(bigseq); all(x in bigset for x in bigsubseq)
7.24 ms ± 78 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

That's just 1.66x faster than the alternative (`set(bigseq) >= set(bigsubseq)`, timed above at 4.36).

So subset testing is generally faster, but not by an incredible margin. On the other hand, let's look at when `all` is faster. What if `items` is ten-million values long, and is likely to have values that aren't in `container`?

```
>>> %timeit hugeiter = (x * 10 for bss in [bigsubseq] * 2000 for x in bss); set(bigset) >= set(hugeiter)
13.1 s ± 167 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
>>> %timeit hugeiter = (x * 10 for bss in [bigsubseq] * 2000 for x in bss); all(x in bigset for x in hugeiter)
2.33 ms ± 65.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Converting the generator into a set turns out to be incredibly wasteful in this case. The `set` constructor has to consume the entire generator. But the short-circuiting behavior of `all` ensures that only a small portion of the generator needs to be consumed, so it's faster than a subset test by *four orders of magnitude*.

This is an extreme example, admittedly. But as it shows, you can't assume that one approach or the other will be faster in all cases.

#### The Upshot

Most of the time, converting `container` to a set is worth it, at least if all its elements are hashable. That's because `in` for sets is O(1), while `in` for sequences is O(n).

On the other hand, using subset testing is probably only worth it sometimes. Definitely do it if your test items are already stored in a set. Otherwise, `all` is only a little slower, and doesn't require any additional storage. It can also be used with large generators of items, and sometimes provides a massive speedup in that case.

Comment: "doesn't work as expected because Python interprets it as a tuple:" To be more precise, it's because of the order of operations: `in` is evaluated before the first `,`.

Answer (score 75):

Another way to do it:

```
>>> set(['a','b']).issubset( ['b','a','foo','bar'] )
True
```

Comment: Fun fact: `set(['a', 'b']) <= set(['b','a','foo','bar'])` is another way to spell the same thing, and looks "mathier".

Comment: As of Python 2.7 you can use `{'a', 'b'} <= {'b','a','foo','bar'}`

Answer (score 29):

If you want to check **all of your input matches**,

```
>>> all(x in ['b', 'a', 'foo', 'bar'] for x in ['a', 'b'])
```

if you want to check **at least one match**,

```
>>> any(x in ['b', 'a', 'foo', 'bar'] for x in ['a', 'b'])
```

Answer (score 13):

I'm pretty sure `in` is having higher precedence than `,` so your statement is being interpreted as `'a', ('b' in ['b' ...])`, which then evaluates to `'a', True` since `'b'` is in the array.

See previous answer for how to do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

The Python parser evaluated that statement as a tuple, where the first value was `'a'`, and the second value is the expression `'b' in ['b', 'a', 'foo', 'bar']` (which evaluates to `True`).

You can write a simple function do do what you want, though:

```
def all_in(candidates, sequence):
    for element in candidates:
        if element not in sequence:
            return False
    return True
```

And call it like:

```
>>> all_in(('a', 'b'), ['b', 'a', 'foo', 'bar'])
True
```

Answer (score 3):

I would say we can even leave those square brackets out.

```
array = ['b', 'a', 'foo', 'bar']
all([i in array for i in 'a', 'b'])
```

Comment: Be careful when using the word `array` for a `list` interchangeably. These two things  are different in Python. Here is the link to the `array` module. https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html

Answer (score 2):

```
[x for x in ['a','b'] if x in ['b', 'a', 'foo', 'bar']]
```

The reason I think this is better than the chosen answer is that you really don't need to call the 'all()' function. Empty list evaluates to False in IF statements, non-empty list evaluates to True.

```
if [x for x in ['a','b'] if x in ['b', 'a', 'foo', 'bar']]:
    ...Do something...
```

Example:

```
>>> [x for x in ['a','b'] if x in ['b', 'a', 'foo', 'bar']]
['a', 'b']
>>> [x for x in ['G','F'] if x in ['b', 'a', 'foo', 'bar']]
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of the answers presented here will not handle repeated elements. For example, if you are testing whether [1,2,2] is a sublist of [1,2,3,4], both will return True. That may be what you mean to do, but I just wanted to clarify.
If you want to return false for [1,2,2] in [1,2,3,4], you would need to sort both lists and check each item with a moving index on each list. Just a slightly more complicated for loop.

Comment: 'both'? There are more than two answers. Did you mean that all the answers suffer from this problem, or only two of the answers (and if so, which ones)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```py
A = ['a','b','c']
B = ['c']
logic = [(x in B) for x in A]
if True in logic:
    do something
```

Answer (score 0):

### Any

In Python3 you can use intersection of sets as an `any`:

```py
>>> {'a','b'} & set(['b', 'a', 'foo', 'bar'])
{'a', 'b'}

>>> {'a','b'} & set(['b', 1, 'foo', 'bar'])
{'b'}
```

of course you could wrap the result in a bool for `True`/`False` values:

```py
>>> bool({'a','b'} & set(['b', 1, 'foo', 'bar']))
True

>>> bool({'c'} & set(['b', 1, 'foo', 'bar']))
False
```

### All

Making use of `is subset:

```py
>>> {'a','b'}.issubset(set(['b', 'a', 'foo', 'bar']))
True

>>> {'a','b'}.issubset(set(['b', 1, 'foo', 'bar']))
False
```

---

### Notes

- `bool()` turns set into boolean
- `issubset()` looks for a set to be a complete subset of another set
- `&` can be used for interesection (any) of sets

The examples can be cleaned up by using variables:

```py
test = {'a','b'}
values = set(['b', 'a', 'foo', 'bar'])

# Any
test & values         # {'a', 'b'}
bool(test & values)   # True

# All
test.issubset(values) # True
```

Answer (score -1):

how can you be pythonic without lambdas! .. not to be taken seriously .. but this way works too:

```
orig_array = [ ..... ]
test_array = [ ... ]

filter(lambda x:x in test_array, orig_array) == test_array
```

leave out the end part if you want to test if **any** of the values are in the array:

```
filter(lambda x:x in test_array, orig_array)
```

Comment: Just a heads up that this won't work as intended in Python 3 where `filter` is a generator. You'd need to wrap it in `list` if you wanted to actually get a result that you could test with `==` or in a boolean context (to see if it is empty). Using a list comprehension or a generator expression in `any` or `all` is preferable.

Answer (score -1):

```
# This is to extract all count of all combinations inside list of 
# list
import itertools

l = [[1,2,3],[6,5,4,3,7,2],[4,3,2,9],[6,7],[5,1,0],[6,3,2,7]]    
els = list(set(b for a in l for b in a))    
sol = {}    

def valid(p):    
    for s in l:    
        if set(p).issubset(set(s)):    
            if p in sol.keys():    
                sol[p] += 1    
            else:    
                sol[p] = 1    

for c in itertools.combinations(els, 2):    
    valid(c)  
# {(0, 1): 1, 
# (0, 5): 1,
# (1, 2): 1,
# (1, 3): 1,
# (1, 5): 1,
# (2, 3): 4,
# (2, 4): 2,
# (2, 5): 1,
# (2, 6): 2,
# (2, 7): 2,
# (2, 9): 1,
# (3, 4): 2,
# (3, 5): 1,
# (3, 6): 2,
# (3, 7): 2,
# (3, 9): 1,
# (4, 5): 1,
# (4, 6): 1,
# (4, 7): 1,
# (4, 9): 1,
# (5, 6): 1,
# (5, 7): 1,
# (6, 7): 3}
```

Comment: This code is unrelated to the question that it has been posted as an answer to.