# Python:How to determine whether the dictionary contains multiple keys?

Tags: python

```
d={'a':1, 'b':2, ...}
if 'a' in d and 'b' in d and ...:
  pass
```

is there a simple way to determine multiple keys at once?
something like:

```
if ['a', 'b'] in d:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
if all(key in d for key in ['a', 'b', 'c', ...]):
```

This may be longer than writing them out separately if you're only testing a couple, but as the list of keys to be tested grows longer, this way will be quicker, since you only have to add the key to the list and not write an additional `in d and`.

Comment: this is essentially the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159313/can-python-test-the-membership-of-multiple-values-in-a-list

Answer (score 2):

```
d={'a':1, 'b':2, ...}
required_keys = set(('a', 'b', ...))

missing_keys = required_keys.difference(d.keys())
if missing_keys
  print "You are missing some keys: ", missing_keys
else:
  print "You have all of the required keys"
```

Comment: you really want set(('a','b','c',...)).issubset(d.keys())

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. It depends upon whether you also need the list of missing keys.

Comment: Right, and you might need the list sorted, etc.
I just meant to point out that difference is doing more than what's required to answer the question, and if the sets are large, this will make a difference in complexity.

Answer (score -3):

len(d.keys()) will let you know how many keys are in your dictionary