# How and operator works in python?

Tags: python

Could you please explain me how and works in python?
I know when

```
x  y  and
0  0   0 (returns x)
0  1   0 (x)
1  0   0 (y)
1  1   1 (y)
```

In interpreter

```
>> lis = [1,2,3,4]
>> 1 and 5 in lis
```

output gives FALSE

but,

```
>>> 6 and 1 in lis
```

output is TRUE

how does it work?

what to do in such case where in my program I have to enter if condition only when both the values are there in the list?

Comment: read it as `6 and (1 in lis)`

Comment: Hint: what does just `1 and 5` print? How about `6 and 1`?

Comment: if i use (6 and 1 ) in lis also it is TRUE how come it is supposed to be false right?

Comment: I think it is `6 and (1 in lis)`, not `(6 and 1) in lis`. Otherwise `0 and 1 in [0]` would evaluate to true.

Comment: @khelwood It's not, see the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @MarounMaroun So by that logic, what is the result of `0 and 1 in [0]` ?

Comment: @MarounMaroun The page you linked to says that `and` has lower precedence than `in`, which supports my interpretation.

Comment: @khelwood Actually you're right! Does this make my answer correct then? ;)

Comment: @MarounMaroun does that mean my very first comment was right?!... so Python hasn't betrayed me after all

Comment: @Pynchia yes :).. sorry. I think it also makes my answer correct. I just misread the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This lines

```
lis = [1,2,3,4]
1 and 5 in lis
```

are equivalent to

```
lis = [1,2,3,4]
1 and (5 in lis)
```

Since `bool(1)` is `True`, it's like writing

```
lis = [1,2,3,4]
True and (5 in lis)
```

now since 5 is *not* in `lis`, we're getting `True` and `False`, which is `False`.

Answer (score 7):

Despite lots of arguments to the contrary,

```
6 and 1 in lis
```

means

```
6 and (1 in lis)
```

It does *not* mean:

```
(6 and 1) in lis
```

The [page](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) that Maroun Maroun linked to in his comments indicates that `and` has a lower precedence than `in`.

You can test it like this:

```
0 and 1 in [0]
```

If this means `(0 and 1) in [0]` then it will evaluate to true, because `0` is in `[0]`.

If it means `0 and (1 in [0])` then it will evaluate to `0`, because `0` is false.

It evaluates to `0`.

Comment: Even better, `0 and 0 in [0]` returns 0, because `and` short-circuits if the first value is "not a true value".

Answer (score 1):

Your statement `1 and 5 in lis` is evaluated as follows:

```
5 in lis --> false
1 and false  --> false
```

and `6 and 1 in lis`  is evaluated like this:

```
1 in lis --> true
6 and true --> true
```

The last statement evaluates to true as any number other than 0 is `true`

In any case, this is the wrong approach to verify if multiple values exist ina list. You could use the `all` operator for this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159313/can-python-test-the-membership-of-multiple-values-in-a-list):

```
all(x in lis for x in [1, 5])
```

Comment: @Jaco, thanks for the answer could you please explain how 6 and 1 returns 1 , x(which is 6) is false and y (which is 1) is true this should return x which is false right?

Comment: @sanyesh: 6 is true! Of numbers, only 0 is false. Check it with `bool(6)`.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is `1 and (5 in lis)`, not `(1 and 5) in lis`.