# Check if tuple contains at least one of multiple values

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

How do I check if a tuple contains values of `100` or `200` ?

I've tried:

```
long_c_ABANDONEDBABY = 100
long_c_HARAMI = 200
# also tried: if (100 or 200)
if (100, 200) in (long_c_ABANDONEDBABY, long_c_HARAMI):
    print "True"
```

But I get false positives, how can I do this?

The question [Can Python test the membership of multiple values in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159313/can-python-test-the-membership-of-multiple-values-in-a-list) is about checking whether a tuple contains **all** of the given values, this question is about containing **at least one** of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any)function  to make the checks like this as:

```
>>> my_tuple = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
>>> check_list = [2, 10]

>>> any(t in my_tuple for t in check_list)
True
```

OR, explicitly make check for individual item using `OR` as:

```
>>> 2 in my_tuple or 10 in my_tuple
True
```

Comment: You could also use `len()`
`>>> test = (1, )`
`>>> test2 = (1, 2)`
`>>> len(test)`
`1`
`>>> len(test2)`
`2`

So just a condition statement `if len(test) > 1:`