# Python 3: Check a string for multiple matches from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function that takes a string and checks to see if there are multiple matches from a separate list in it.

Let's say the list is:

```
fruits = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pineapple', 'Durian', 'Lychee']
```

And the input string is:

```
"Apple, Orange"
```

I'd like it to return a **True** if two or more items from the list are in the input string.

So:

```
"Durian, Apple, Orange"
```

would return **True**. But:

```
"Apple"
```

would return **False.**

I'm just not quite sure how to iterate over the input string. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: You can call `.split()` on the input string which will give you a list, then follow the steps [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159313/can-python-test-the-membership-of-multiple-values-in-a-list).

Comment: `sum(1 for x in input_str.split(', ') if x in fruits) >= 2`

Comment: `len([a for a in your_str.split(', ') if a in fruits])>1`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I think I know what to do from here. :)

Comment: @tyteen4a03 The function on the linked page returns a false if another fruit that's not in the list is added.So, 

    "Grape, Apple, Orange" 

returns **False.** How would I get it to return **True** as long as two or more are in the original list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also want to count repetition (i.e., input string `'apple, apple'` would also return True), then the following line should do the job.

```
sum(f in fruits for f in fruit_str.split(', ')) > 1
```

If you want to check for uniqueness as well, you can preprocess the input string and remove the duplicates before checking for their presence in the fruit list.

```
sum(f in fruits for f in set(fruit_str.split(', '))) > 1
```

Comment: You can also use the intersection operator `&` , which should be more efficient than a loop.  `len(set(fruit_str.split(', ')) & set(fruits)) >= 2`

Comment: @HåkenLid: That's another way to do it but I've doubt that & or intersection is faster than a loop. Doesn't that need a loop anyway?

Comment: In the underlying C implementation there's presumably a loop. But the lookup is constant time, since set is implemented as a hash map.