# Python Boolean "In" and "Or" Statements Together

Tags: python, python-2.7, boolean, boolean-expression

Say I want to check if either of two given elements are present in a given tuple, like:

```
if foo in my_tuple or bar in my_tuple:
```

Is there a more pythonic way to frame this expression? Specifically, if I want to check for several elements, the statements becomes annoyingly long. I've tried

```
if (foo or bar) in my_tuple:
```

But this chooses foo over bar and checks only for foo. Would appreciate any inputs on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Python test the membership of multiple values in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159313/can-python-test-the-membership-of-multiple-values-in-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get a lot of elements that you need to compare it's better to check intersection of `set` objects:

```
if {foo, bar, other_vars} & set(my_tuple):
```

**BUT** keep in mind that values should be [**hashable**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable), if not, look at [Rory Daulton answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44433301/3124746)

Answer (score 10):

This is pythonic and would work:

```
if any(v in my_tuple for v in [foo, bar, eggs, spam, parrot, lumberjack]):
```

Comment: You have to grok the Monty Python references ;)