# How to check two variables against two values

Tags: python

I have two variables, `a` and `b`, and I have some combinations:

- `a` is blank and `b` is `None`
- `a` is `None` and `b` is blank
- `a` is blank and `b` is blank
- `a` is `None` and `b` is `None`

and I need to match all the four conditions **in one line**. I am trying to do with:

```
if ((a, b) in ['', None, '', None]))
```

However, this does not produce the desired result.

Comment: You're asking if a tuple is in a list of strings and Nones, which it never will be. Ask instead if it's in a list *of tuples*, where it might be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Python test the membership of multiple values in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159313/can-python-test-the-membership-of-multiple-values-in-a-list)

Comment: "all the four conditions in one line" - why? Do you have a shortage of newline characters in your environment?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a list of tuples:

```
if (a,b) in [(None, None),("", None),("", ""),(None, "")]:
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
if set((a, b)) <= set((None, "")):
```

`<=` between `set`s tests if one is a [subset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset) of the other.

Comment: Its also faster then others answers (constructing `list` of `tuples`).

Answer (score -1):

do this

```
cond = [('', None),(None,''),('',''),(None, None)] 
if (a,b) in cond:
    # code
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it solves the problem.

Comment: @BDL `print('hello world)` no point to  explain what print does  or how it works, above code is in plain english and easy to understand