# Checking if two integers are in the same list of list

Tags: python

I have a list of list like this:

```
l = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

and I want to check whether one of the lists in the list of lists have say integer 3 and 5 in the same array. So in my example here, `l[1]` has both integers 3 and 5. How would I go about finding that?

Comment: Anything you've tried so far? Please update the question with your code.

Comment: If you just want a boolean "does it exist", something like `any((3 in x and 5 in x) for x in l)` should work.

Comment: How would you do it with a simple list? Try to find a solution for that task and then loop over this code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Python test the membership of multiple values in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159313/can-python-test-the-membership-of-multiple-values-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use enumerate() for indexing.

IDLE Output :

```
>>> l = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
>>> integer1 = 3
>>> integer2 = 5

>>> for index, nested_list in enumerate(l):
    if integer1 in nested_list and integer2 in nested_list:
        print(f"Both integers are in l[{index}]")
        print("List is " + str(l[index]))


Both integers are in l[1]
List is [3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```py
l = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]

if 3 in l[1] and 5 in l[1]:
    print("both numbers are in this array", l[1])
```

Comment: oh i see i will fix it

Comment: fixed it, it should work now