# Two simplified conditions in one

Tags: python

I would like to make a condition with two possibilities in the same string:

```
for k in string:
    if 'www.housemike.com/b' in k:
        do something
```

and

```
for k in string:
    if 'www.housemike.com/c' in k:
        do something
```

Is it possible to make this more simplified than:

```
for k in string:
    if 'www.housemike.com/b' or 'www.housemike.com/c' in k:
        do something
```

Maybe would it be possible with a regular expression between "b" and "c"?

Comment: maybe you could shorten this line to make it look cool but it would be harder to-understand, I'd suggest you stick to this `if or` for simplicity

Comment: Is `k` a string or a list?

Comment: I have modified the code to make it clearer
Thanks everyone for your help

Comment: I hope you're aware that your current merged condition doesn't do what you think it does. It should be `'www.housemike.com/b' in k or 'www.housemike.com/c' in k:`

Comment: OR [Can Python test the membership of multiple values in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159313/can-python-test-the-membership-of-multiple-values-in-a-list) , whatever `k` is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regex approach with `re.search`:

```
for item in k:
    if re.search(r'^www\.housemike\.com/[bc]$', item):
        do something
```

I am assuming that you want to match entire strings which are these URLs.  If not, and you can tolerate substring matches, then just remove the `^` and `$` anchors from the regex and use:

```
www\.housemike\.com/[bc]
```

Comment: @khelwood I was assuming that the OP were looking for exact matches of the URL in a list of strings, and did not want a substring match.  Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Use `any()` with a list:

```
if any('www.housemike.com/'+x in k for x in ['b','c']):
  # do something
```