# Python "in" with multiple variables

Tags: python

So I've got this piece of code:

```
OPTION_1 if (i in (0, 1, 2) and j in (0, 1, 2)) else OPTION_2
```

It does `OPTION_1` only if `i` and `j` are in the given range. I wonder if I can shorten it somehow. Tried this:

```
OPTION_1 if (i and j) in (0, 1, 2) else OPTION_2
```

But if `i==4` and `j==2`, it does `OPTION_1`, despite `i` not being in the range.

Comment: That's because `4 and 2 == 2`.

Comment: `all(map(lambda x: x in (0, 1, 2), [i, j]))` <---- it's not shorter, but if you need to consider _N_ variables instead of 2, it might help

Comment: If you do need to scale this up to a larger number of variables you could do this trick with sets, `if len({0, 1, 2}.intersection({i, j})) == len({i, j}):` This way you are not repeatedly searching lists or tuples for values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Python test the membership of multiple values in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159313/can-python-test-the-membership-of-multiple-values-in-a-list)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use sets: the `<=` operator tests if all elements of the first set are elements of the second set.

```py
OPTION_1 if {i, j} <= {0, 1, 2} else OPTION_2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `all` option to check for each variable.

```
OPTION_1 if all(x in (0,1,2) for x in (i,j)) else OPTION_2
```

With this, you can check as many variables as you want or as many values you want.

```
OPTION_1 if all(x in range(3) for x in (a,b,c,d,e,f)) else OPTION_2
```

This will be equivalent to checking :

```
if a in (0,1,2,) and b in (0,1,2,) and c in (0,1,2,) and d in (0,1,2,) and e in (0,1,2,) and f in (0,1,2,)
```

The `all` option will check if each if statement is `True`. If all of them are `True`, then `all` will be set to `True`. It will break as soon as the first one is `False`. Similar to `all`, you can use `any` as well. `any` works when you want to check for any one of them matching the condition. Normally used when you want to use the `or` option.

In your if statement, you are giving the following:

```
if 4 and 2
```

In Python, 0 is false and 1 is True (any positive number greater than 0 is True).

The above statement results in:
if True and True
It always results the rightmost number. If the equation was a False, it will ignore the rightmost number and return False.

If condition such as `if 2 and 4` will return `2`

If condition such as `if 4 and 2` will return `4`

If condition such as `if 0 and 4` will return `0`

If condition such as `if 4 and 0` will return `0`

Your code is doing the following:

```
OPTION_1 if (i and j) in (0, 1, 2) else OPTION_2
```

Translated as:

```
OPTION_1 if (4 and 2) in (0, 1, 2) else OPTION_2
```

equates to:

```
OPTION_1 if (2) in (0, 1, 2) else OPTION_2
```

The output of this is True so resulting in OPTION_1.

Comment: `(4 and 2)` doesn't evaluate to 2, it evaluates to True i.e. **1**

Comment: @NishithSavla, agreed it evaluates to True. However, try it on your python shell. The result is 2. I just tried it again.

Comment: oh yaa it is a very strange behaviour.

Comment: I found this on official python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not, which states the fact.

Answer (score 0):

An easy and clean solution is

`OPTION_1 if {i, j} < {0, 1, 2} else OPTION_2`

**Explanation:**

If `a` and `b` are sets, then `a < b` tests whether `a` is a proper subset of `b`.

See [Python's built-in set operators](https://docs.python.org/release/3.7.9/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset).