# Search for several string in text files and if exits remove a file

Tags: python

I've an example.txt which contains hexadecimal data like this.

```
09 06 07 04 00 00 01 00 1d 03 4b 2c a1 2a 02 01   
b7 09 01 47 30 12 a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14   
07 f0 a1 0b 80 00 81 00 84 01 00 86 00 85 00 83   
07 91 94 71 06 00 07 19

09 06 07 04 r0 00 01 00 1d 03 4b 2c a1 2a 02 01   
b7 09 01 47 30 1s a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14   
07 f0 a1 0b 80 00 81 0d 84 01 00 86 00 85 00 83   
07 91 94 71 06 

09 06 07 04 r0 00 01 00 1d 03 4b 2c a1 2a 02 01   
b7 09 01 47 30 1s a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14   
07 f0 a1 0b 80 00 81 0d 84 01 00 86 00 85 00 83   
b7 09 01 47 30 1s a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14

b7 09 01 47 30 1s a0 0a 80 08 33 04 03 92 22 14   
07 f0 a1 0b 80 00 81 0d 84 01 00 86 00 85
```

What I want to do is to look for a specific string and if exits **continue at that point** looking for another string and so on. Once I know that patterns exits then I want to remove a file and if that pattern doesn´t exits remove another.

My code is this:

```
import os

with open('example.txt') as file:
    if '12' in file.read():
        if ('80' or '25' or 'a6' or '1b') in file.read():
            if '04' in file.read():
                if '07' in file.read():
                    command1 = 'rm -f file2.json'
                    os.system(command1)
     else:
     command2 = 'rm -f file1.json'
     os.system(command2)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow. Questions on the site need to be specific. Asking for contributors to design a program for you is not the purpose of Stackoverflow. Can you reframe your question as a specific problem? Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance on how to ask a good question for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Chris this seems like a pretty straight forward question including code he already tried to me.

Comment: Yes, on reflection, agreed.

Comment: I don't see a question here... Is there something wrong with the presented code? If so - please give details about it. If not - this is better suited for [codereview.se]

Comment: It was a new version to show what I was doing to a person who asked me. It's solved now

Comment: Also please see: [Why can't I call read() twice on an open file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file) and [Can Python test the membership of multiple values in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159313/can-python-test-the-membership-of-multiple-values-in-a-list)

Comment: Also see [How to delete a file or folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-to-delete-a-file-or-folder). There is no reason to call external shell commands. You can call Python functions to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions (regex) to find all groups with this structure in the file.

```
import os
import re

file_path = "example.txt"
delete_file_path = "delete_me"
delete_file_ending = ".txt"
pattern = re.compile("12.*(?=[90|25|30]).*(?=40).*(?=20)")  # add a proper regex here to match all you required strings properly

with open(file_path) as file:
    text = file.read()
paragraphs = text.split(os.linesep)
paragraph_tokens = [re.findall(pattern, paragraph) for paragraph in paragraphs]

for i in range(paragraph_tokens):
    if paragraph_tokens[i]:
        os.remove(delete_file_path +s tr(i) + delete_file_ending)
```

you could also get re.match, if you only want to know if any matched pattern is in there, but then you would change the if condition a little bit since re.match returns an object.

Comment: This looks great but how could add several strings in re.compile(). Could I do this? `re.compile("12" and( "80" or "25")`

Comment: Because my idea is once "12" exits start seaching for a "80" or "25"

Comment: This is a tutorial for regex: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html
in your case you either capture all tokens like "[12|80|25] and do the logic later (which does probably not help a lot in your case) or you caputure a group by using look-ahead or look behind features described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings
in this case I would strongly advise to import regex instead of import re, since the regex library also supports look-aheads which the default re library does not.

Comment: https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/regex.html is the correct ressource to learn about lookahead in regex in this case.

Comment: It gives me this error that I dont know why because I'm working with strings `unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'`. I'm using your initial idea using re

Comment: You can see on the post

Comment: pattern = re.compile("12.*(?=[80|25|a6|1b]).*(?=04).*(?=07)")

Comment: That is for regex?

Comment: yes :) explanation: 12 then anything then either 80 or 25 or a6 or 1b, then anything, then 04, then anything, then 07.

Comment: That's great. Change your answer I will give as corrected. Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to comment that I want to stop looking for that sequence when I have a jump line. I mean I have a huge text file which is divided into paragraphs so I want to search for that pattern in ech paragraph and when the paragrahp is finished to start again doing the searching from the starting point

Comment: I think the way to do that is like establishing a break point  whenever It encountered a blank space but I dont know how to implement. Any idea? @Semmel

Comment: I added this feature. If anything else comes up (like reading line by line if the file is bigger than the available ram ...), pls ask a separate question for it since the original question was hopefully properly answered by now :)

Comment: That's great. Thanks a lot!