# Where is the mistake in my Python If-statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

I try to check if two chars 'x' and '+' are in the array ['+', '-']. I get "True" as the result of this check, even though 'x' is obviously not in the array.

```
if 'x' and '+' in ['+', '-']:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

I also tried to check this:

```
if 'x' and '-' in ['x', 'y']:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

This works correctly, 'False' gets printed. What is the mistake?

Comment: See also the other Q&As linked there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159313/how-to-test-the-membership-of-multiple-values-in-a-list

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this because the first part of both the expressions is True.

```
'+' in ['+', '-']

True

'-' in ['x', 'y']

False

if 'x' and '+' in ['+', '-']:

#if True('x' is considered Boolean True as it is non-zero) AND True

#True
```

Take an example this:

```
if 0 and '+' in ['+', '-']:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')

output
False
```

#reason `0` is considered `False` in Boolean and other things are `True`, so it will be

```
False AND True

False
```

Comment: In your second example, the last part won't even get evaluated, as False and whatever is already decided by the first False.

Comment: Its boolean `FALSE` AND `TRUE`. Gave this example to OP to make them understand that `if x`  is `True` in their example if we put `if False` then there will be different result.