# Python: detect strings that share words

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of single and multi-word phrases:

`terms = ['Electronic rock', 'Alternative rock', 'Indie pop']`

I want to detect that `terms[0]` and `terms[1]` share the word `rock`. Is there a Pythonic way to do this, instead of using a ton of for-loops, temporary lists, and `split(' ')`?

Basically, I'm trying to detect a half-equality of phrases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a dictonary to remember which words appear in which terms:

```
from collections import defaultdict

terms = ['Electronic rock', 'Alternative rock', 'Indie pop']
d = defaultdict(list)
for term in terms:
    for word in term.split():
        d[word].append(term)

for k,v in d.iteritems():
    if len(v) > 1:
        print k,v
```

Output:

```
rock ['Electronic rock', 'Alternative rock']
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/o9EKK)

Comment: haha I was halfway through typing almost the exact same thing... Maybe a 2.7+/3+ guy will show us a terser Counter example?

Answer (score 1):

This is a terribly inefficient solution for these simple list elements but for longer strings you could use [itertools' combinations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to generate a set of 2-entry lists and then [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) to compare the strings.  If you're just dealing with two or three word phrases, this solution is not for you.

Answer (score 1):

visit [How to find list intersection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432/python-how-to-find-list-intersection)
I think the answer could think from this.  In your question, we don't know what's the result you want to present.  I think you'd better list the result which you want to get.

Here I list the result which can give you some hint. (Well, without split, I don't think that will be clear to understand).

```
a=terms[0].split()
b=terms[1].split()
list(set(a) & set(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

Some variations on the answer of @MarkByers:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>>
>>> terms = [
...     'Electronic rock', 'Alternative rock', 'Indie pop',
...     'baa baa black sheep',
...     'Blackpool rock', # definition of "equality"?
...     'Rock of ages',
...     ]
>>>
>>> def process1():
...     d = defaultdict(list)
...     for term in terms:
...         for word in term.split():
...             d[word].append(term)
...     for k,v in d.iteritems():
...         if len(v) > 1:
...             print k,v
...
>>> def process2():
...     d = defaultdict(set)
...     for term in terms:
...         for word in term.split():
...             d[word.lower()].add(term)
...     for k,v in d.iteritems():
...         if len(v) > 1:
...             print k, sorted(list(v))
...
>>> process1()
rock ['Electronic rock', 'Alternative rock', 'Blackpool rock']
baa ['baa baa black sheep', 'baa baa black sheep']
>>> process2()
rock ['Alternative rock', 'Blackpool rock', 'Electronic rock', 'Rock of ages']
>>>
```