# How to find common elements in list of lists?

Tags: python, list, recursion, comparison

I'm trying to figure out how to compare an n number of lists to find the common elements. 
For example:

```
p=[ [1,2,3],
    [1,9,9],
      ..
      ..
    [1,2,4]

>> print common(p)
>> [1]
```

Now if I know the number of elements I can do comparions like:

```
for a in b:
  for c in d:
    for x in y:
...
```

but that wont work if I don't know how many elements p has. I've looked at this solution that compares two lists
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1388864/1320800

but after spending 4 hrs trying to figure a way to make that recursive, a solution still eludes me so any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: How to find list intersection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432/python-how-to-find-list-intersection)

Comment: does your solution have to be recursive? Can you use built-in `intersect` functions (that is, is this homework?)?

Comment: I didn't know that the proper term was "intersection" so thanks for that. It will help me look into it more. Now, it doesn't have to be recursive but we just learned about recursion so I figured that probably I would have to compare p[0] and p[1] and then feed the result to the rest of the elements, that's why I thought that probably it would be a recursive solution

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You are looking for the set intersection of all the sublists, and the data type you should use for set operations is a set:

```
result = set(p[0])
for s in p[1:]:
    result.intersection_update(s)
print result
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I knew nothing about sets so I'm going to research some more. However from a preliminary test p = [[1,2,3], [1,3], [8,1]] the solution you proposed instead of [1] it returns [8,1] ?

Comment: @user1320800: The first version of this answer had a wrong `print` statement in the end.  Of course we must print `result`, not `s`.

Comment: Alternatively, `result &= s`.

Comment: thank you for your help! it works great and now I know what sets are :)

Comment: [Raymond's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10067138/500584) uses the ability of `set.intersection` in Python 2.6+ to avoid the loop entirely.

Comment: Adding to @JoelCornett 's comment, you can use `result &= set(s)` instead of `result.intersection_update(s)`.

Answer (score 28):

A simple solution (one-line) is:

```
set.intersection(*[set(list_) for list_ in p])
```

Answer (score 27):

The [set.intersection()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) method supports intersecting multiple inputs at a time.  Use [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to pull the sublists out of the outer list and pass them into `set.intersection()` as separate arguments:

```
>>> p=[ [1,2,3],
        [1,9,9],
        [1,2,4]]

>>> set(p[0]).intersection(*p)
set([1])
```

Comment: The asterisk in `set(p[0]).intersection(*p)` is an unpacking operator, if anyone is looking for a "googable" term.

Answer (score 17):

Why not just:

```
set.intersection(*map(set, p))
```

Result:

```
set([1])
```

Or like this:

```
ip = iter(p)
s = set(next(ip))
s.intersection(*ip)
```

Result:

```
set([1])
```

edit:

copied from console:

```
>>> p = [[1,2,3], [1,9,9], [1,2,4]]
>>> set.intersection(*map(set, p))
set([1])
>>> ip = iter(p)
>>> s = set(next(ip))
>>> s.intersection(*ip)
set([1])
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing something but passing p=[ [1,2,3],
    [1,9,9],
    [1,2,4]] didn't seem to work

Answer (score 3):

```
p=[ [1,2,3],
    [1,9,9],
    [1,2,4]]

ans = [ele[0] for ele in zip(*p) if len(set(ele)) == 1]
```

Result:

```
>>> ans
[1]
```

Comment: Try this with p=[[1,2],[2,1]].  Or even p=[[1,2],[2]].

Comment: My code only works, if we a looking at all common elements that are also in the same position; that's the whole gist of the zip(*p) thing. That's what I thought OP wanted, but reading the post again, I probably misunderstood. I also assumed that every sublist has the same length.

Comment: Also, `zip` will drop elements if the lists vary in length.

Comment: exactly, sublists not always of the same length, thank you for the help nonetheless!

Comment: This is a really great answer for a different problem. I use this to find common columns :  [len(set(c))==1 for c in zip(*p)]

Comment: eg, to get the indices of each common column (as a list)... [i for i,c in enumerate(zip(*q)) if len(set(c))==1]

Answer (score 1):

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, (set(i) for i in p))
```

Comment: `reduce` isn't considered "Pythonic" by many. Also, your version requires each list be converted to a set, and an additional new set to be created for each intersection. Sven's version creates only one set.

Comment: @agf: Understood. Still, it is a working solution (albeit a slightly inefficient one).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the set intersection of all the sublists, and the data type you should use for set operations is a set:

```
result = set(p[0])  
for s in p[1:]:
   result.intersection_update(s)
print result
```

However, there is a limitation of 10 lists in a list. Anything bigger causes 'result' list to be out of order. Assuming you've made 'result' into a list by `list(result)`.

Make sure you `result.sort()` to ensure it's ordered if you depend on it to be that way.