# How to check if a python dictionary keys has same value(s) and extract those value(s)

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to know how to extract values in a dictionary that appear for all keys.

So for instance, if i have the following dictionary:

```
d = {'a': [num_1, num_2], 'b': [num_1],
                'c': [num_1,num_2, num_3]}
```

I would like to extract the value which exists for all keys, in this instance num_1.

How can i achieve this?

**EDIT:** how would i store the common value(s) in a list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find common elements in list of lists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066642/how-to-find-common-elements-in-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
d = {'a': ['num_1', 'num_2'], 'b': ['num_1'], 'c': ['num_1', 'num_2', 'num_3']}

vals = d.values()
uniq = set(vals[0])

for lst in vals[1:]:
    uniq.intersection_update(lst)

# now `uniq` holds the intersected values:
print uniq
> set(['num_1'])

# to get the result as a list:
uniq = list(uniq)
print uniq
> ['num_1']
```

Comment: You don't need to call `set` on every list, just one -- `set` methods take any iterable.

Comment: Thanks Oscar. Now how can i get the result as a standalone list?
['num_1'] instead of set(['num_1'])

Comment: I think i figured it out. Cheers!

Comment: @greenhoodlum please don't forget to accept the answer that was most helpful for you, by clicking on the check mark to its left.

Answer (score 0):

Convert all the values to sets and then take their intersection:

```
set.intersection(*(set(v) for v in d.values()))
```

Comment: You can't call `set.intersection` with a first argument that isn't a set. You also don't need to make every list into a `set`.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to 'set'. trying to read up on it now. is there way to store the common value(s) in a list?

Comment: You can just convert it using `list`. See the other answers, which are a bit more efficient than this.

Answer (score 0):

My odd working way

```
vals = [i for v in d.values() for i in v]
set([i for i in vals if vals.count(i) == len(d.values())])
```

Answer (score -1):

list(set(d['a']) & set(d['c']) & set(d['b']))

This should help