# How to find common link among multiple lists?

Tags: list

I'm trying to figure out how to compare n number of lists to find the common  link among the lists. For example following are the lists:

```
A = [1,2,3],
B = [3,4,5,6],
C = [6,7,8],
D = [4,5,6],
      ..
      ..
```

The input to this program will be  A and C (looking for a way to find a common link between A & C)

```
The expected output is 
C-->B-->A (A & C are linked through B)
```

The challenge might be find deeper level of connections e.g.

```
A = [1,2,3],
B = [3,4,5,6],
C = [6,7,8],
D = [8,9,10],
E = [10,11,12]      ..
      ..
```

The input to this program will be  A and E (looking for a way to find a common link between A & E)

```
The expected output is 
E-->D-->C-->B-->A (A & E are linked through D,C,B)
```

I've looked at this solution that compares two lists but it is solving a very different problem: [How to find common elements in list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066642/how-to-find-common-elements-in-list-of-lists)

Comment: What is your programming language?

Comment: can you define "common link"? I cannot understand how B and A are linked

Comment: are elements in array always sorted and have no gaps? can there be several links?

Comment: Programming language: preferably java but it could be any.

Comment: By common link I mean a common element amon the lists. In the above example (that I have corrected) A and C lists have nothing in common. So the program searches for a list that has some. B and C have element '6' in common while A and B have element '3' in common. Hence a connection between A and C.

Comment: Elements are not always sorted or without the gaps. But I can sort them and remove the gaps if it helps. Yes, there can be multiple links the program can list the shortest path or all the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem you need:

1. build graph from existing arrays

compare every array with every other array and create edge with weight 1 if at least one element is common, HashSet will help you

2. find shortest path

as soon as you have graph, you can use any path finding algorithm, I suggest you to start with [Floyd–Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) as simplest one