# Compare lists within a python to list to find common elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

consider a list of lists as given here.

```
many_lists = [[1,999,91,120,11], [909,800,7620,11], [1,101,800,7620]]
```

the output of this should be:

```
output_lst = [11, 1, 800, 7620]
```

I need to compare each list with the rest of the lists and if there is a common element then it should be in the output.

is there a simpler way to do this without two loops?

edit: (order within the output_list is not important)

Comment: Convert the lists to sets, intersect them, and convert the final result back to a list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find common elements in list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066642/how-to-find-common-elements-in-list-of-lists)

Comment: @Barmar I don't think that answers this because the intersection of all lists is empty here and is not the expected output.

Comment: I see, it's the elements that are common to any pair of sublists, not all sublists.

Comment: @Barmar  This is not a duplicate, OP wants to find items that appear in two lists at least, not all of them - and apparently in the order when the duplicates appear, but that should be made clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to run a [counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) over the [flattened list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/9332187) and choose those that appeared more than once:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

flattened = chain.from_iterable(many_lists)

result = [elem
          for elem, count in Counter(flattened).items()
          if count > 1]
```

to get

```
>>> result
[1, 11, 800, 7620]
```

Comment: you can also flatten with `sum(many_lists, [])`

Comment: @oskros true, but that's an anti-pattern perhaps `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Without third loop, using set and intersaction:

```
many_lists = [[1,999,91,120,11], [909,800,7620,11], [1,101,800,7620]]

alist = []
for _ind, id in enumerate(many_lists):
    for j in many_lists[_ind+1:]:
        alist.append(list(set(id) & set(j)))
print(*alist)
```