# compare two lists in python and return indices of matched values

Tags: python, list, match, indices

For two lists a and b, how can I get the indices of values that appear in both? For example,

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [9, 7, 6, 5, 1, 0]

return_indices_of_a(a, b)
```

would return `[0,4]`, with `(a[0],a[4]) = (1,5)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: How to find list intersection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432/python-how-to-find-list-intersection)

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of that one even though it may be similar.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to make `b` a `set` since you are only checking for membership inside it.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = set([9, 7, 6, 5, 1, 0])
>>> [i for i, item in enumerate(a) if item in b]
[0, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! What about this case:  'a = [1, 2, 9, 8]' and 'b = [1, 9, 1]' (b is a subset of a) where the desired result is '[0, 2, 0]' (the indices of a matching each value in b)? Making b a set will lose the index of the second '1' as well as the sequence of the indices.

Comment: In that case wouldn't it be `[0, 2, 0, 1, 2]` or something similar? (since all the items of `b` occur in both lists)

Comment: I haven't been clear... The resulting `indices` I need in this case will give `array(a)[indices] = b`. I've edited the question. maybe the description there is clearer.

Comment: You should open your second case up as a new question as nobody will see it here.

Answer (score 6):

```
def return_indices_of_a(a, b):
  b_set = set(b)
  return [i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v in b_set]
```

Answer (score 3):

For larger lists this may be of help:

```
for item in a:
index.append(bisect.bisect(b,item))
    idx = np.unique(index).tolist()
```

Be sure to import numpy.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this,with no need to set :

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = {9, 7, 6, 5, 1, 0}
[i for i, item in enumerate(a) if item in b]
```

inspired by @jamylak