# I have a list of lists, how to extract index of sublists with common values?

Tags: python

I want the index of items from following list of lists which have overlapping elements.

```
slist = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Output should be like:

```
[0,1,2] and [3]
```

I tried the following but it gives me pairs of values from which it is difficult to segregate values as I expect

```
    for ((i,a),(j,b)) in itertools.combinations(enumerate(slist),2):
        if len(a.intersection(b)) > 0:
            print("overlapping",i,j)
        else:
            print("non overlapping",i,j)
```

```
Output:
('non overlapping', 0, 1)
('non overlapping', 0, 2)
('overlapping', 0, 3)
('overlapping', 1, 2)
('non overlapping', 1, 3)
('non overlapping', 2, 3)
```

Comment: to have a complete question here, you could post the result of your print function, but anyway someone will solve it in the next 5mins, you can but nice code boxes on stack overflow with ``` your code ```

Comment: Are the sublists with overlapping values consecutive @jaya?

Comment: Not necessarily

Comment: What should be the output of this : `[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]`

Comment: What does the `[0,1,2] and [3]` means ? Can you explain how do you find this output ?

Comment: @CorentinLimier This should give me three lists of indices, [0], [1] and [2] since none of them overlap

Comment: @AlexandreB. These are two lists of indices. [0,1,2] are indices of sublist with overlapping values, while [3] does not overlap with any.

Comment: `@CorentinLimier This should give me three lists of indices, [0], [1] and [2] since none of them overlap` - ??? [1,2] clearly has common element with [2,3]. That's overlapping. Unless you mean that one list contain the other

Comment: @h4z3 Actually I do not expect such values in my input list. My list is actually a list of ranges like [range(6,100), range(1,100), range(105,300)]. I do not expect single value overlaps. Sorry for the confusion, I should have explained more.

Comment: if you see a similiar post on stackoverflow, you could try: `index_dict = dict((value, idx) for idx,value in enumerate(slist[0]))`, followed by `[index_dict[x] for x in slist[1]]`, this will compare the first two sublists of your list and gives back the indices, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385647/list-match-in-python-get-indices-of-a-sub-list-in-a-larger-list

Comment: @PV8 I have compared two sublists at a time and fetched indices (posted in question). But I am not able to collate indices of all overlapping sublists together.

Comment: So you need to check containment. What about cases like 1-100, 20-80, 50-100? Are they grouped together because the largest one contains them all? Or as two pairs of containment? Or does it never happen?

Comment: Your code and example data produce an Exception: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'intersection'` - can you provide a [mcve]. Also your use of `.intersection` implies that `[1,2]` and `[2,3]` do *overlap*.

Comment: Also, why do you even have a list of elements in range? Can we convert them to just pairs for the solution?

Comment: @h4z3 That may happen, in this case (the list being  [(1-100), (20-80), (50-100)]) the output has to be [0,1,2] which are indices of all three elements since they are overlapping/contained

Comment: @wwii Its (if len((set(a)).intersection(set(b))) > 0) I had initially created the sublists using set, hence the error

Comment: `if len((set(a)).intersection(set(b))) > 0:` - still will get overlap instead of containment. For containment this len should be `== min(len(set(a)),len(set(b)))` (intersection of two sets in which one contains the other is the smaller set).

Comment: @h4z3 I do not want a distinction between containment and overlap. The output of using intersection is fine for me.

Comment: But you said yourself that `[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]` should return 3 separate groups in your case? Now you say something completely different than what you answered earlier.

Comment: @h4z3 The problem statement that I had considers [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]] as non-overlapping. I also clarified that I am not dealing with edge overlaps in ranges. To that extent, the two solutions proposed here work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using a list comprehension:

```
>>> slist = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
>>> sets = tuple(map(set, slist))
>>> list(map(list, {tuple(i for i, _s in enumerate(sets) if s & _s) for s in sets}))
[[0, 1, 2], [3]]
```

If it makes it more readable/understandable I’m only using map to make the tuples into lists again. You need to use tuples as lists and sets are unhashable. If you don’t map list then it’s more readable but it results in a list of tuples.

```
list({tuple(i for i, _s in enumerate(sets) if s & _s) for s in sets}))
```

Comment: Great solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

- Create a dictionary to keep for each sublist the potential other overlapping list
- Define a overlapping function between two lists. You can use `intersection` between two `set`.
- Then for each sublist combination, you look if they overlap. If they, you save the index of each other. To find the combination, I use the `itertools.combinations` as in the question.
- Finally, to get the expected output, you need to remove the duplicates from the dictionary.

Here's the code:

```
import itertools

slist = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [7, 8, 9, 10]]

# Dictionary to keep overlapping index
dict_ = {i: [i] for i in range(len(slist))}

# Iterate all combination
for combo in itertools.combinations([i for i in range(len(slist))], 2):
    sublist_1 = slist[combo[0]]
    sublist_2 = slist[combo[1]]
    # Check if they overlap
    if len(set(sublist_1).intersection(set(sublist_2))) > 0:
        # Save index
        dict_[combo[0]].append(combo[1])
        dict_[combo[1]].append(combo[0])

print(dict_)
# {0: [0, 1, 2], 1: [1, 0, 2], 2: [2, 0, 1], 3: [3]}

# Order each sublist in list of index to then remove duplicates
list_ = [set(sub) for sub in (list(dict_.values()))]

print([list(i) for i in set(map(tuple, list_))])
# [[0, 1, 2], [3]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will test this with other combinations as well