# how do I compare two lists in python by indexes

Tags: python

I've to compare two lists by indexes, if in list 1 index is equal to 0 than all elements in list2 are 0.

```
list1 = [0, 1, 1, 0]   # that's for example 
list2 = [[15, 19, 13, 15, 30, 14, 14], [14, 22, 30, 19, 29, 17, 15], [19, 21, 11, 25, 23, 23, 30], [15, 15, 25, 18, 22, 24, 29], [24, 30, 30, 11, 25, 18, 27]]
```

output:

```
list2 = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [14, 22, 30, 19, 29, 17, 15], [19, 21, 11, 25, 23, 23, 30], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367020/compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-indices-of-matched-values)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [compare two lists in python and return indices of matched values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367020/compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-indices-of-matched-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should also do:

```
list1 = [0, 1, 1, 0]   # that's for example 
list2 = [[15, 19, 13, 15, 30, 14, 14], [14, 22, 30, 19, 29, 17, 15], [19, 21, 11, 25, 23, 23, 30], [15, 15, 25, 18, 22, 24, 29], [24, 30, 30, 11, 25, 18, 27]]

result = [[0] * len(list2[index])  if index == 0 else list2[index] for index in list1]

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [0, 1, 1, 0] 
list2 = [[15, 19, 13, 15, 30, 14, 14], [14, 22, 30, 19, 29, 17, 15], [19, 21, 11, 25, 23, 23, 30], [15, 15, 25, 18, 22, 24, 29], [24, 30, 30, 11, 25, 18, 27]]
new_list=[]
for i in list1:
  for index,j in enumerate(list2):
    if(i==index):
      new_list.append([x*i for x in j] )
      break 
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

My take without any if statements

```
list1 = [0, 1, 1, 0]
list2 = [[15, 19, 13, 15, 30, 14, 14], [14, 22, 30, 19, 29, 17, 15], [19, 21, 11, 25, 23, 23, 30], [15, 15, 25, 18, 22, 24, 29], [24, 30, 30, 11, 25, 18, 27]]

output_list = []
for index, item in enumerate(list1):
    output_list.append([element * item for element in list2[index]])
print(output_list)
```