# Find non-common elements in lists

Tags: python, algorithm, list, set, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to write a piece of code that can automatically factor an expression. For example, 
if I have two lists [1,2,3,4] and [2,3,5], the code should be able to find the common elements in the two lists, [2,3], and combine the rest of the elements together in a new list, being [1,4,5].

From this post: [How to find list intersection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432/python-how-to-find-list-intersection)
I see that the common elements can be found by

```
set([1,2,3,4]&set([2,3,5]).
```

Is there an easy way to retrieve non-common elements from each list, in my example being [1,4] and [5]?

I can go ahead and do a for loop:

```
lists = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,5]]
conCommon = []
common = [2,3]
for elem in lists:
    for elem in eachList:
    if elem not in common:
        nonCommon += elem
```

But this seems redundant and inefficient. Does Python provide any handy function that can do that? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you want get separate lists like [1,4] and [5], or a single one [1,4,5]?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Use the symmetric difference operator for `set`s (aka the XOR operator):

```
>>> set([1,2,3]) ^ set([3,4,5])
set([1, 2, 4, 5])
```

Comment: oh wow thanks!! Bue does the above code take equal amount of computation time and memory space as set([1,2,3])&set([3,4,5])? Or it doesn't have a significant influence on code performance?

Comment: It is the most efficient way to accomplish your goal. Its complexity is on the same order as `&` (namely, linear in the number of elements in the sets).

Answer (score 18):

Old question, but looks like python has a built-in function to provide exactly what you're looking for: `.difference()`.

**EXAMPLE**

```
list_one = [1,2,3,4]
list_two = [2,3,5]

one_not_two = set(list_one).difference(list_two)
# set([1, 4])

two_not_one = set(list_two).difference(list_one)
# set([5])
```

This could also be written as:

```
one_not_two = set(list_one) - set(list_two)
```

**Timing**

I ran some timing tests on both and it appears that `.difference()` has a slight edge, to the tune of 10 - 15% but each method took about an eighth of a second to filter 1M items (random integers between 500 and 100,000), so unless you're *very* time sensitive, it's probably immaterial.

**Other Notes**

It appears the OP is looking for a solution that provides two separate lists (or sets) - one where the first contains items not in the second, and vice versa.  Most of the previous answers return a single list or set that include all of the items.

There is also the question as to whether items that may be duplicated in the first list should be counted multiple times, or just once.

If the OP wants to maintain duplicates, a list comprehension could be used, for example:

```
one_not_two = [ x for x in list_one if x not in list_two ]
two_not_one = [ x for x in list_two if x not in list_one ]
```

...which is roughly the same solution as posed in the original question, only a little cleaner.  This method would maintain duplicates from the original list but is *considerably* (like multiple orders of magnitude) slower for larger data sets.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Intersection concept to deal with this kind of problems.

```
b1 = [1,2,3,4,5,9,11,15]
b2 = [4,5,6,7,8]
set(b1).intersection(b2)
Out[22]: {4, 5}
```

Best thing about using this code is it works pretty fast for large data also. I have b1 with 607139 and b2 with 296029 elements when i use this logic I get my results in 2.9 seconds.

Comment: This does not answer the original question. The ask is the opposite.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `.__xor__` attribute method.

```
set([1,2,3,4]).__xor__(set([2,3,5]))
```

or

```
a = set([1,2,3,4])
b = set([2,3,5])
a.__xor__(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use symmetric_difference command

x = {1,2,3}
y = {2,3,4}

z = set.difference(x,y)

Output will be : z = {1,4}

Answer (score 0):

This should get the common and remaining elements

```
lis1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,1]
lis2=[4,5,8,7,10,6,9,8]

common = list(dict.fromkeys([l1 for l1 in lis1 if l1 in lis2]))
remaining = list(filter(lambda i: i not in common, lis1+lis2))
```

`common  = [4, 5, 6]`

`remaining = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 8, 7, 10, 9, 8]`

Answer (score 0):

All the good solutions, starting from basic DSA style to using inbuilt functions:

```
# Time: O(2n)
def solution1(arr1, arr2):
  map = {}
  maxLength = max(len(arr1), len(arr2))
  for i in range(maxLength):
    if(arr1[i]):
      if(not map.get(arr1[i])):
        map[arr1[i]] = [True, False]
      else:
        map[arr1[i]][0] = True
    if(arr2[i]):
      if(not map.get(arr2[i])):
        map[arr2[i]] = [False, True]
      else:
        map[arr2[i]][1] = False

  res = [];
  for key, value in map.items():
    if(value[0] == False or value[1] == False):
      res.append(key)

  return res

def solution2(arr1, arr2):
  return set(arr1) ^ set(arr2)

def solution3(arr1, arr2):
  return (set(arr1).difference(arr2), set(arr2).difference(arr1))

def solution4(arr1, arr2):
  return set(arr1).__xor__(set(arr2))

print(solution1([1,2,3], [2,4,6]))
print(solution2([1,2,3], [2,4,6]))
print(solution3([1,2,3], [2,4,6]))
print(solution4([1,2,3], [2,4,6]))
```

Answer (score 0):

With pandas:

```py
s1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
s2 = pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

intersection = np.intersect1d(s1, s2)
np.union1d(s1[~s1.isin(intersection)], s2[~s2.isin(intersection)])
```