# python - find common elements of different types in lists

Tags: python, algorithm, set

I'm wondering if Python provides any handy function for finding common elements in different lists?

Say I have two lists,

```
[1,2,[3,4]] and [1,3,[3,4]]
```

The ideal output of the function should be [1,[3,4]], a list containing the common elements. What troubles me is the nested list [3,4]. Without it I can simply do set(list1)&set(list2) and this question will become a complete duplicate of know this question might look little duplicating from [Find non-common elements in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348347/python-find-common-elements-in-lists) . When I tried the same thing with the example above, I got an error saying:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Any idea how to deal with it? 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was starting to type that :)

Comment: If you really want to do a set intersection, you need to turn your inner lists into tuples

Comment: In the case that the objects are not all _hashable_ but are _sortable_, you can sort both lists and step through them, making for an O(n*log(n)) instead of the O(n*n). These lists _are_ sortable in Python2, but no longer in Python3

Comment: @gnibbler Can you explain in a bit more detail how to step through the lists to make a O(n*log(n))?

Comment: @Jimster, see F.J's answer. `x in b` is O(n) if b is a `list` or a `tuple`, but would be O(1) for a `dict` or a `set`. Since you can't have a set with lists in it, you are forced to use the o(n) search if you do it this way

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = [1,2,[3,4]]
>>> b = [1,3,[3,4]]
>>> [x for x in a if x in b]
[1, [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following commands and output from an IDLE session should help solve your problem:

```
>>> A = [1,2,[3,4]]
>>> B = [1,3,[3,4]]
>>> [a for a in A if a in B]
[1, [3, 4]]
```

Comment: Thanks... but I've never used IDLE!

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case it *is* possible to make the members of the list hashable, by using `repr`:

```
>>> a = [1,2,[3,4]]
>>> b = [1,3,[3,4]]
>>> a_set = set(repr(x) for x in a)
>>> [x for x in b if repr(x) in a_set]
[1, [3, 4]]
```

Comment: This is a bad idea, `repr()` won't necessarily return the same thing for two objects that would compare equal.  One example is sets and dictionaries, where the displayed order is arbitrary and often dependent on insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

You could cheat a little and make a helper function (depending on your Python version):

```
import collections

a = [1,2,[3,4]]
b = [1,3,[3,4]]

def helper(item):
    for i in item:
        if not isinstance(i, collections.Hashable):
            yield tuple(i)
        else:
            yield i

print set(helper(a)) & set(helper(b))
```

But I like MRAB's answer...