# Python - eliminating common elements from two lists

Tags: python-3.x

If i have two lists:

```
a = [1,2,1,2,4] and b = [1,2,4]
```

how do i get

```
a - b = [1,2,4]
```

such that one element from b removes only one element from a if that element is present in a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [*itertools.zip_longest*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) to zip the lists with different length then use a list comprehension :

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> [i for i,j in izip_longest(a,b) if i!=j]
[1, 2, 4]
```

Demo:

```
>>> list(izip_longest(a,b))
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (1, 4), (2, None), (4, None)]
```

Comment: i get the following error - ImportError: cannot import name 'izip_longest'

Comment: @hmm sorry as  you are in python 3 you need `zip_longest` fised!

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,1,2,4] 
b = [1,2,4]
c= set(a) & set(b)
d=list(c)
```

The answer is just a little modification to this topic's answer:
[Find non-common elements in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348347/find-common-elements-in-lists)

and since you cannot iterate a set object:
https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/462906/typeerror-set-object-does-not-support-indexing

Comment: You could do `set(a) - set(b)`, but this will also remove all the duplicates and scramble up the order, which might not be intended.