# Common List Elements

Tags: python-2.7

Alright, so I have a small issue:

```
def common(a,b,c):
    a.sort()
    b.sort()
    c.sort()
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0
    common=False
    while i<len(a) and j<len(b):
        if a[i] == b[j]:
            if b[j] == c[k]:
                return True
            else:
                k = k+1
                continue
        else:
            if i == len(a):
                j = j+1
            else:
                i = i+1
    return common
a=[3, 1, 5, 10]
b=[4, 2, 6, 1]
c=[5, 3, 1, 7]
print common(a,b,c)
```

Basically, it has to tell me if there are common elements in the lists. With 1 it works, but if I replace the 1's with 8's, it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'j' never increase, 1 is working because after `sort` it is the 1st element and doesn't need `j` to be increased.

My suggestion is convert your lists to sets and check the common elements using intersection(&)

```
def common(a,b,c):
    common = set(a) & set(b) & set(c)
    return True if common else False


a=[3, 8, 5, 10]
b=[4, 2, 6, 8]
c=[5, 3, 8, 7]
print common(a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current algorithm only works if the smallest value in the `b` list is common to the other lists. If there's a different common value, you'll never find it, because you'll increment `i` until it is `len(a)`, then quit.

I think you need to change your logic so that you increment the index of the list that points at the smallest value. If `a[i]` is less than `b[j]`, you need to increment `i`. If `c[k]` is less still, you should increment it instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you've programmed is not doing at all what you expect, so you need to rethink your logic. If you look at your loop, you first check if `a[0]` matches `b[0]`. Nope, so add to `i`. Then you compare `a[1]` to `b[0]`, nope and so on. If nothing matches `b[0]`, you exit the loop without ever checking the other elements of `b`. It works with 1's in your lists because after you sort, those happen to be in the first position in all three lists.

In any case, this is pretty clunky. There's a much easier way of doing this via set intersection. See this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348347/find-common-elements-in-lists).