# How to find match items from two lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: How to find list intersection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432/python-how-to-find-list-intersection)

I have two lists of data in a .txt

```
data1 = "name1", "name2", "name3", "name4" etc.

data2 = "name3", "name6", "name10" etc.
```

I want to find out which names appears in both list
How would I do it?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use [sets](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

```
set(data1) & set(data2)
```

The `&` operator means "give me the intersection of these two sets"; alternatively you can use the `.intersection` method:

```
set(data1).intersection(data2)
```

Comment: I find the .intersection more readable personally, but as you say they do the same thing.

Comment: @ivanhoifung If this solved your problem you should [accept this answer by clicking the checkmark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) next to the answer. It'll reward both parties with some points, and mark this problem as solved.

Comment: This is a great answer and works for most cases (including the question posed above). However, this answer will not work if you are just trying to compare lists in any order and you want to account for duplicates as sets eliminate duplicates.

Comment: @PeterGraham: in which case you'd use `Counter()` objects, which are multisets.

Comment: Does this preserve the order (e.g two lists of sorted timestamps)? And are they computationally equivalent?

Comment: @Maikefer: sets do not retain ordering. In that case create a set only for `data2` and use a list comprehension that tests values against that set: `data2_set = set(data2)` and `[v for v in data1 if v in data2]`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks! If I know that there are no duplicates in my list, then there is no need for the conversion into a set, right?

Comment: @Maikefer: you still want to create a set, because containment testing is way faster that way. I didn't consider duplicates in `data1`, you'd want to use `members = set(data1).intersection(data2)` and `[v for v in data1 if v in members]` to remove duplicates in that case.

Answer (score 14):

```
nf = [x for x in data1 if x in data2]
nf
```

would return the common item in both lists

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [ name for name in data1 if name in data2 ]
['name3']
```

Answer (score -3):

```
For a in data1:
    for b in data2:
        if a==b:
        print(a)
```

That's one way to do it, not the best way though

Comment: Typo in "For" and missing indent.