# Get a nested list that not stored in another list

Tags: python, list

I have an input list that look like this

```
input_list = ["a", "b2","d"]
```

and another list that look like this

```
ref_list = [['a'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'], ['d']]
```

What I want to do is to get the list of value from input_list that not existed in ref_list
So, the result based on these values should be

```
[['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']]
```

At first, my case only have something like

```
input_list = ["a","b","d"]
ref_list = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

which I can use

```
missing_value = list(set(ref_list) - set(input_list))
```

which will extract a result like this

```
["c"]
```

but for the case that a ref_list that each index is a list with single or multiple value in it. Is there a simple way to achieve the missing value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a job for `set.isdisjoint`:

```
input_list = ["a", "b2","d"]
ref_list = [['a'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'], ['d']]

res = list(filter(set(input_list).isdisjoint, ref_list))

print(res)
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY27CgMhFER7v0JsroIEsqZIky8RCetjiWFxRe8W@XpjXJI0U5xhzuQXPrakrrm0FlPe8b7GivRGNZuZpMxOTDLPDClh@VUaZjCSarBnkBTsNFIdzA3mBnNq5OVoPBhDuqh2x0fFl7hiKLwG5P9vcYrVx/rcYkJJv7dCkFw64X0uWnsD)):

```
[['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']]
```

Benchmark with your small data:

```
 2.6 μs   2.6 μs   2.7 μs  python_user
 2.2 μs   2.2 μs   2.2 μs  Uttam_Velani
 0.9 μs   0.9 μs   0.9 μs  dont_talk_just_code
```

Benchmark with a 1000 times longer `ref_list`:

```
2150 μs  2184 μs  2187 μs  python_user
1964 μs  1981 μs  1990 μs  Uttam_Velani
 292 μs   304 μs   306 μs  dont_talk_just_code
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZNfjpswEMbfOcUIaYu9stIkrKoqEsdoXxCyDDatUzCubaT2bj1Dr5T6T0hINxv1pX4Aa/hm5jefsf7pvk6q/KjN6dSbaQQnRyEdyFFPxoERWjCXZVz0oKOUzlYYJJWeHR2kdcRr@rjDhwz8MsLNRkEtoZ8MSJDqogDZAxsGdAQ1ufAhaY5xe6mIm9Tvk3NspJ/FwJR83PD7LI3gqUUFdRPDoTJnjq0BUkJYnmQQClnhUBBheAdhv6LAUFWwvWa8arVhWgvFU/569BtVmoVPylHHhm/0OFtHu4mLf/AwRFAvB@cd/4tuIy2X9jhJtc7GWdbPqrPehdVpkRsryT2YLGE6Yd1dLgJqHttQyts6Mp/uf5MzrPihRReMj63rbXN/ssuhBFk4lCi/@muEnYelzIMSYWnj50ZLRnVGIDF1Q6lio6A0yZPUG7O0p/GHYOqLQCW@tn9AFlaYN9hq/a0QHKV7gQY2tpwdHiAvxlXphXF9KJubygnwGa2MRQ7en/NwBIuXJSLgu0PeDBoPsc5ZTiBv9znJed6QJKvrghUNgbpodwWBot3HZ5liXYx1MdaV8fmSvvCiWUrstn6d92n8CHaA4ulls@vh9y8LBTwBClF4hp344H/L/8QU6l9x9m9x8TeoTqc/)):

```
from timeit import repeat

def python_user(input_list, ref_list):
    return [i for i in ref_list if all(j not in i for j in input_list)]

def Uttam_Velani(input_list, ref_list):
    required_list = []
    for data in ref_list:
        if len(set(data) & set(input_list)) == 0:
            required_list.append(data)
    return required_list

def dont_talk_just_code(input_list, ref_list):
    return list(filter(set(input_list).isdisjoint, ref_list))

funcs = python_user, Uttam_Velani, dont_talk_just_code


def test(input_list, ref_list, number, format_time):
    expect = funcs[0](input_list, ref_list)
    for func in funcs:
        result = func(input_list, ref_list)
        print(result == expect, func.__name__)
    print()

    for _ in range(3):
        for func in funcs:
            times = sorted(repeat(lambda: func(input_list, ref_list), number=number))[:3]
            print(*(format_time(t / number) for t in times), func.__name__)
        print()

test(["a", "b2","d"],
     [['a'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'], ['d']],
     10000,
     lambda time: '%4.1f μs ' % (time * 1e6))
test(["a", "b2","d"],
     [['a'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'], ['d']] * 1000,
     20,
     lambda time: '%4d μs ' % (time * 1e6))
```

Comment: @python_user Right, but at least the data they've shown as well as their own non-list solution also using sets suggest that their elements indeed are hashable.

Comment: Nice comparison! All solutions worked well. The ref_list that I worked has about 15+ indexes so I think it will not make a huge different in term of run time. For the input and ref list, they will come as nested list like the example shown.

Comment: Anyway, I've never used `isdisjoint` before. I searched and found this function but isn't it come with the parameter like `set.isdisjoint(another_set)` ? Not sure if its has any difference?

Comment: @Jamiewp Well, yes, it is called later. Not by me directly but by `filter`. That takes the `isdisjoint` method bound to the `set(input_list)` object and calls it with each element of `ref_list` as argument.

Answer (score 2):

It quit simple and I can not think of any efficient way to solve your problem.

```
input_list = ['a', 'b2','d']

ref_list = [['a'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'], ['d']]

required_list = []

for data in ref_list:
    if len(set(data) & set(input_list)) == 0:
        required_list.append(data)

print(required_list)
```

Output:

```
[['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']]
```

Also you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615041/how-to-find-match-items-from-two-lists) for more clarity.
Thanks!