# Exact match of lists intersection using regex.findall in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I would like to get the intersection of to lists of words using regex. It's C implementation making it runs faster is of huge importance in this particular case... Even though I have a code almost working, it would also match 'embeded-words', like "buyers" and "buy" for exemple.

Some code probably explains it better. This is what I have so far:

```
re.findall(r"(?=(" + '|'.join(['buy', 'sell', 'gilt']) + r"))", ' '.join(['aabuya', 'gilt', 'buyer']))
>> ['buy', 'gilt', 'buy']
```

While this is what I would like:

```
re.exactfindall(['buy', 'sell', 'gilt'], ['aabuya', 'gilt', 'buyer'])
>>['gilt']
```

Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're basically looking for intersection of two lists?(one is your list from sentences and another is a given list.) see answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432/how-to-find-list-intersection

Comment: I'm talking about regular-expression here actually. But thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this using regexps, the easiest way is probably to include word breaks (`\b`) in the matching expression, (outside the catch) giving you:

```
re.findall(r"\b(?=(" + '|'.join(['buy', 'sell', 'gilt']) + r")\b)",
    ' '.join(['aabuya', 'gilt', 'buyer']))
```

which outputs `['gilt']` as requested.

Comment: Nice! That's it. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

```
listgiven=['aabuya', 'gilt', 'buyer']
listtomatch=['buy', 'sell', 'gilt']
exactmatch = [x for x in listgiven if x in listtomatch]
print(exactmatch)
```

Comment: Thanks, but since regex is implemented in C and runs faster, I'd rather try to find a solution using regex.findall if possible...