# how to get matched items from python dictionary? when values are arrays

Tags: python, dictionary

I've a dictionary as shown below:

```
dict={0:['hamburger','cheese'], 1:['hamburger']}
```

I would like to know which is the fastest way to get the every item which are both in 0 and 1, like 'hamburger' in this example

Comment: What do you want to get? `0` and `1` since those keys have the values present?

Comment: I guess, if you want linear lookup you'll need a set. List is quadratic - one `n` for the dictionary and another for the list.

Comment: Please include code you have tried, Also be more specific on what your desired output is

Comment: i want to get item which are both in 0 and 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the intersection of your two dict values. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432/how-to-find-list-intersection) gives a solution.

```
dict={0:['hamburger','cheese'], 1:['hamburger']}
l = list(set(dict[0]) & set(dict[1]))
print(l)
> ['hamburger']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
[key for key in dict.keys() if 'hamburger' in dict[key]]
```

The list of indexes will be present in z

Comment: hamburger is just for example 
 
i want to get every item which are both in 0 and 1

Comment: @GiorgiAbashidze "i want to get every item which are both in 0 and 1". How about you add that sentence to your question because unlike your Original post, this actually tells us what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
f=0
for i in d:        #d- dictionary
    if f==0:
        m=set(d[i])
        f=1
        continue
    m=m & set(d[i])   # get intersection. note: there will be no duplicate elements
print list(m)
```

or

```
m=set(d[d.keys()[0]])   # ensure dictionary has at least one key

for i in d.keys()[1:]:
    m=m & set(d[i])
print list(m)
```