# How to create an array from two others that will contain common pairs (sequences) of numbers?

Tags: python

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8]
b = [6,8,9,4,5,3,2,1]
```

final result should be

```
c = [6,8,4,5]
```

This array contains the same pair of numbers in both arrays - how to write this kind of code in python?

I only known how to create an array with duplicated values

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8]
b = [6,8,9,4,5,3,2,1]
c = [x for x in a if x in b]
print (c)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find list intersection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432/how-to-find-list-intersection)

Comment: Why should final result be `c = [6,8,4,5] `?

Comment: I think you want to check 2(pair) item at a time in second list right?

Comment: final array should contains duplicated pair/pairs of number that are next to each other - so in that case only pairs - (4,5) and (6,8) match this condition - cause both are in two arrays - a and b

Comment: @ŁukasPtak Next time try to be that clear when first asking your question, it might have saved it being put on hold as unclear :)

Comment: @NickA: because both lists contain the 2-tuples `4,5` and `6,8`

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> [e for t in [t for t in zip(b,b[1:]) if t in zip(a,a[1:])] for e in t]
[6, 8, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This is great! Very elegant.

Comment: How did you even figure out what OP was trying to do

Comment: @NickA. OP has mentioned `duplicated pairs of numbers` in the title :)

Comment: @Sunitha That is one of the most obscurely asked questions I've seen on SO >.<

Comment: I commend you for figuring out what the OP wanted. I was clueless.

Comment: quick and elegant.

Comment: @NickA. I have to agree on that.. Even I had to think for a while to figure what OP was asking

Comment: sorry for causing such a problem.
But yes - final array should contains duplicated pair/pairs of numbers that are next to each other - so in that case only pairs (6,8) and (4,5) fulfill this condition