# Find Common Items Between Two Lists With Repeated Elements Using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list, repeat

A lot of [posts](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-find-the-intersection-of-two-lists-or-the-number-of-elements-that-are-the-same-in-two-given-lists-in-Python) or [How to find list intersection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432/how-to-find-list-intersection) aim to find to `unique` items between two lists:

Here are my two lists:

```
list1=[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 10, 12] 
list2=[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 8, 18]
```

my answer is to find common items, the items can be repeated. for example, one `1` appears in those two lists, therefore, `res` should contain one `1`. Two `2` appear in the two lists, `res` should contain two `2`, etc.

```
res = [1 ,2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

The order does not matter, my attempt is to use:

```
res = [x for x in list2 if x in list1]
# res = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5] by above code
```

However, it is not correct, so how  can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find list intersection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432/how-to-find-list-intersection)

Comment: Actually, my result list can contain repeat items.

Comment: There is a suitable answer to your question on that page.

Comment: @DYZ there isn't...  All answers for that question remove duplicate intersections, hence the emphasis on `unique` in jason's question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could think to do this is by removing items from `list2` as you go:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 10, 12]
list2 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 8, 18]

res = []

for x in list1:
    if x in list2:
        res.append(x)
        list2.remove(x)

print(res)
```

I'm curious if there are better answers out there.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional approach won't work since inside the second `for` loop it iterates the entire list again and finds the same element again even though it was considered earlier.

You need a mechanism to eliminate the element which is already considered.
Eg: When you iterate `list1` over `list2` and come across `3`.
In the first iteration, you'll find it in the `list2`. But, as you move forward and consider the next element which is again `3`, you'll again find it as a common element in `list2` since you are iterating the `list2` from the beginning.

#### Here's a solution:

Once we come across a duplicate element in `list2`, we remove it from `list2`.

```py
a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 10, 12]
b = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 8, 18]

def remove_duplicates(x,y):
    res = []
    for i in x:
        for j in y:
            if j == i:
                res.append(j)
                y.remove(j)
    return res
    
print(remove_duplicates(a,b))
```

Another approach using **functional programming** would be to covert the `list2` into a data structure using `map()` such that it holds two values for each element in the list: `[(1, True),(2, True), ...]`

While iterating, only visit elements who are set to `True`
And, whenever we find a common element, we set that element's `True` to `False`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution based on Counter:

```
import collections

def intersection(A,B):
    c_a=collections.Counter(A)
    c_b=collections.Counter(B)
    duplicates=[]
    for c in c_a:
        duplicates+=[c]*min(c_a[c],c_b[c])
    return duplicates


list1=[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 10, 12] 
list2=[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 8, 18]
print(intersection(list1,list2))
```