# Remove the intersection of two list of sets from both lists, and append it to a new list in python

Tags: python, list, set

I want to take the intersection of the list of sets `x1,y2`, remove them from both lists, then append it to a new list 'res'.
This is my code: (which works I think)

```
x1=[{'A'},{'B'},{'c'},{'D'}]
y1=[{'A'},{'B'},{'C'},{'d'}]
res=[]
for i in x1:
    if i in y1:
        res.append(i)
        x1.remove(i)
        y1.remove(i)
for i in y1:
    if i in x1:
        res.append(i)
        x1.remove(i)
        y1.remove(i)
print(x1,y1)

>[{'c'}, {'D'}] [{'C'}, {'d'}]

print(res)    

>[{'A'}, {'B'}]
```

I also tried this from that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432/how-to-find-list-intersection):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [1,3,5,6]
>>> list(set(a) & set(b))
[1, 3, 5]
```

But when it's a list of sets, this gives errors:

```
x1=[{'A'},{'B'},{'c'},{'D'}]
y1=[{'A'},{'B'},{'C'},{'d'}]
res=[]
res.append(list(set(x1) & set(x2)))
print(x1,y1)
print(res)

>TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Is there any better methods to write this ?
Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Update:

```
x1=[{'A'},{'B'},{'c'},{'D'}]
y1=[{'A'},{'B'},{'C'},{'d'}]
x2= {e for i in x1 for e in i}
y2= {e for i in y1 for e in i}
z1 = x2.intersection(y2)
res = [{e} for e in z1]
x1=[{e} for e in x2-z1]
y1=[{e} for e in y2-z1]
print(x1,y1)
>[{'c'}, {'D'}] [{'C'}, {'d'}]
print(res)
>[{'A'}, {'B'}]
```

But when the set have size more then one:

```
x1=[{'A','B'},{'B'},{'c'},{'D'}]
y1=[{'A'},{'B'},{'C'},{'d'}]
x2= {e for i in x1 for e in i}
y2= {e for i in y1 for e in i}
z1 = x2.intersection(y2)
res = [{e} for e in z1]
x1=[{e} for e in x2-z1]
y1=[{e} for e in y2-z1]
print(x1,y1)
>[{'D'}, {'c'}] [{'C'}, {'d'}]
print(res)
>[{'B'}, {'A'}]
```

Which suppose output:

```
x1=[{'A','B'},{'B'},{'c'},{'D'}]
y1=[{'A'},{'B'},{'C'},{'d'}]
res=[]
for i in x1:
    if i in y1:
        res.append(i)
        x1.remove(i)
        y1.remove(i)
for i in y1:
    if i in x1:
        res.append(i)
        x1.remove(i)
        y1.remove(i)
print(x1,y1)
>[{'B', 'A'}, {'c'}, {'D'}] [{'A'}, {'C'}, {'d'}]
print(res)
[{'B'}]
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert those *lists of sets* into *sets of frozensets*, take the intersection and then convert back:

```
x1=[{'A'},{'B'},{'c'},{'D'}]
y1=[{'A'},{'B'},{'C'},{'d'}]

def list_of_sets_to_set_of_frozensets(l):
    return set(map(frozenset, l))

def set_of_frozensets_to_list_of_sets(s):
    return list(map(set, s))

res = set_of_frozensets_to_list_of_sets(list_of_sets_to_set_of_frozensets(x1) & list_of_sets_to_set_of_frozensets(y1))

print(x1,y1)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, by using `.intersection()` method.

```
>>> x1=[{'A'},{'B'},{'c'},{'D'}]
>>> _x1= {e for i in x1 for e in i}     
>>> _x1     
{'c', 'B', 'D', 'A'}
>>> y1=[{'A'},{'B'},{'C'},{'d'}]        
>>> _y1= {e for i in y1 for e in i} 
>>> _y1 
{'d', 'B', 'A', 'C'}
>>> z1 = _x1.intersection(_y1) # intersection
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> [{e} for e in z1]   
[{'B'}, {'A'}]

>>> print(x1,y1)
[{'c'}, {'D'}] [{'C'}, {'d'}]
```

**Explanation:**

- Converted list of sets to set and store them into a temporary variable and used `.intersection()` provided by
  built-in function `set()`.
- Finally, converted to your required format(i.e., list of sets)

Comment: I finally figured it out, Thanks!

Comment: I think using this method seems still have some bugs, please check the update

Comment: @Manx I have stored in `_x1`, `_y1`, i guess u haven't observed the previous edit.