# How can I compare two lists elements in Python 3.8?

Tags: python, list, compare, element

For example:

if two lists elements are

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [2,3,4,5,6]
```

and I want to get `[2,3,4,5]` because its sharing the same number?
Can somebody help me?

Oh, and by the way, how to wrote the code if the a and b is random list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find list intersection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432/how-to-find-list-intersection)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use list comprehension or set union:

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [2,3,4,5,6]

res = [x for x in a if x in b]
res_set = set(a) & set(b)

print(res)     # [2, 3, 4, 5]
print(res_set) # {2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [2,3,4,5,6]

c=[x for x in a if x in b]
d=[y for y in (a+b) if y not in c]

print(c)    # [2, 3, 4, 5]
print(d)    # [1,6]
```

You can get the same element and get different elements.