# Pythonic and efficient way to find all the different intersections between two partitions of the same set

Tags: python, numpy, set, partitioning, intersection

I need to find all the different intersections between two partitions of the same set. For example, if we have the following two partitions of the same set

```
x = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
y = [[1, 3, 6, 7], [2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10]]
```

the required result is

[[1], [2], [3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9, 10]].

In detail, we calculate the cartesian product between every subset of x and y, and for each of these products, we classify the elements in new subsets accordingly if they belong to the intersection of their associated subsets or not.

What is the optimal / more pythonic way to do it? Thanks in advance!

---

PERFORMANCE COMPARISON OF THE CURRENT ANSWERS:

```
import numpy as np

def partitioning(alist, indices):
    return [alist[i:j] for i, j in zip([0]+indices, indices+[None])]

total = 1000
sample1 = np.sort(np.random.choice(total, int(total/10), replace=False))
sample2 = np.sort(np.random.choice(total, int(total/2), replace=False))

a = partitioning(np.arange(total), list(sample1))
b = partitioning(np.arange(total), list(sample2))

def partition_decomposition_product_1(x, y):
    out = []
    for sublist1 in x:
        d = {}
        for val in sublist1:
            for i, sublist2 in enumerate(y):
                if val in sublist2:
                    d.setdefault(i, []).append(val)
        out.extend(d.values())
    return out

def partition_decomposition_product_2(x, y):
    all_s = []
    for sx in x:
        for sy in y:
            ss = list(filter(lambda x:x in sx, sy))
            if ss:
                all_s.append(ss)
    return all_s

def partition_decomposition_product_3(x, y):
    return [np.intersect1d(i,j) for i in x for j in y]
```

And measuring execution time with %timeit

```
%timeit partition_decomposition_product_1(a, b)
%timeit partition_decomposition_product_2(a, b)
%timeit partition_decomposition_product_3(a, b)
```

we find

```
2.16 s ± 246 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
620 ms ± 84.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
1.03 s ± 111 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

thus the second solution is the fastest one.

Comment: I wonder if working with arrays helps at all!  You have lists of different length, and expect results that also differ.  Those `numpy` `set` functions depend heavily on sorting, where as python's own `set` class uses hashing (as done with `dict` keys). Speed/efficiency in `numpy` is the result of doing whole-array calculations with compiled methods.  That doesn't seem to be an option here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @hpaulj. It happens that as is hinted in the decomposition function, the rows come directly from numpy arrays, that's why I used those numpy sets implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the two lists are partitions of the same set is not relevant to the algorithm choice. This boils down to iterating through two lists of lists and getting the intersection between each combination (you can add that assertion at the beginning of the function to ensure they are partitions of the same set, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/12568761) to flatten the lists efficiently). With this in mind, this function accomplishes the task, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43092875/12568761) to calculate list intersection:

```
def func2(x, y):
    # check that they partition the same set 
    checkx = sorted([item for sublist in x for item in sublist])
    checky = sorted([item for sublist in y for item in sublist])
    assert checkx == checky

    # get all intersections
    all_s = []
    for sx in x:
        for sy in y:
            ss = list(filter(lambda x:x in sx, sy))
            if ss:
                all_s.append(ss)
    return all_s
```

Then using [this time comparison method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10872313/12568761), we can see that this new function is ~100x faster than your original implementation.

Comment: Wow! that one line defining ss it's quite impressive, it makes all the work :) I will check your answer carefully and time compare it with the other ones. Thanks a lot, @tiberius

Comment: I suggested an edition to your answer where I included the existence condition for the ss list to be appended to the final list all_s

Comment: I also edited checky definition including y, and not x

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but this script produces the result you have in your question:

```
x = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
y = [[1, 3, 6, 7], [2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10]]

out = []
for sublist1 in x:
    d = {}
    for val in sublist1:
        for i, sublist2 in enumerate(y):
            if val in sublist2:
                d.setdefault(i, []).append(val)
    out.extend(d.values())

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: Hi Andrej. It reproduces the result, indeed :) It is WAY simpler than mine hahaha. I just need to check your suggestion in my general case, and I will come back to accept the answer if it works :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I may miss some details, but it seems a bit too easy:

```
[np.intersect1d(a,b) for a in x for b in y]
```

Output:

```
[array([1]),
 array([2]),
 array([3]),
 array([4, 5]),
 array([6, 7]),
 array([ 8,  9, 10])]
```

The above includes duplicates, for example `x=[[1,2,3],[1,4,5]]` and `y=[[1,6,7]]` would gives `[[1],[1]]`.

---

If you want to find the **unique** intersections:

```
[list(i) for i in {tuple(np.intersect1d(a,b)) for a in x for b in y}]
```

Output:

```
[[8, 9, 10], [6, 7], [1], [4, 5], [2], [3]]
```

Comment: OMG this is embarrassing to me hahaha, only one line! I think @tiberius' solution is a bit faster though. Thanks, Quang.