# How to check which if list_b contains any elements of list_a and check which elements of list_a are in list_b? This is what I'm doing so far:

Tags: python, list

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list_b = [8, 9, 5, 10]


check =  any(item in list_a for item in list_b)
```

This is what I'm doing to check if there are elements from list_A in list_b but I want to know which exactly are these elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432/how-to-find-list-intersection

Answer (score 0):

You can covert them to `set` and try the below code:

```
list_a = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
list_b = set([8, 9, 5, 10])

check = list_a.intersection(list_b)
print(check)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use set(), but i don't know the requirements about your code:

```
math_items = list(set(list_a) & set(list_b))
```

You have to keep in mind that set() eliminates the repeated elements in the list leaving only one, I don't know if this works for you, since I don't know if you should also count how many times that element appears in the other list.

Answer (score -1):

Caveat: This approach is not a good idea for big lists but it's easy to understand.

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list_b = [8, 9, 5, 10]

for firstItem in list_a: # Take each item in the first list,
  for secondItem in list_b: # and check it against each item in the second list.
    if firstItem == secondItem: # If the items match,
      print(firstItem, 'is in both lists') # then print the item.
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted.  It clearly and simply answers the OP's question, it does not require a type conversion and runs in one third of the time of the code above.