# Python Array Intersection

Tags: python-3.x, list

This is my code to find values common between 2 arrays.

```
li1 = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
li2 = [int(h) for h in input().split()]
for m in li1 :
    for j in li2 :
        if m == j :
            print(m, end=" ")
            j = float("-inf")
            break
```

When I do `li1 = [5, 5, 5]` and `li2 = [5, 5]`, it returns 5 5 5. I want this to be `5` as `li2` only has two `5`. How can I do this.

Comment: Use `set`s: [How to find list intersection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432/how-to-find-list-intersection)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same more simply by using `set`s and `intersection`:

```py
li1 = [1, 2, 3]
li2 = [2, 3, 4]
shared = list(set(li1).intersection(set(li2))

print(shared) # prints [2, 3]
```