# Sorting lists with indexing for easy item removal

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, lambda

I am facing the following problem. I have multiple lists in Python that I want them to have them sorted with a sort of indexing in order to remove items from the other lists. Let me further explain.

```py
listA_ID = [1,2,3,5,6,7] # integer from 0-250
listA_Var1 = [3.9, 4.7, 2.1, 1.2, 0.15, 0.99]

listB_ID = [2,5,6,7,8,10] # integer from 0-250
listB_Var1 = [0.54, 0.35, 1.19, 2.45, 3.1, 1.75]
```

```py
>> After Comparison of listA_ID & listB_ID I should end up with the common IDs.
listA_ID = listB_ID = sorted(list(set(listA_ID) & set(listB_ID)))
listA_ID = [2,5,6,7]
listB_ID = [2,5,6,7]
```

Therefore I want to delete the elements [1, 3] from listA_ID which are in the positions of [0, 2] of that list and the same thing from listA_Var1, delete [3.9, 2.1] which are in the same positions [0, 2].

Similarly, I want to remove the elements [8, 10] from listB_ID which are in the positions of [4, 5] of that list and the same thing from listB_Var1, delete [3.1, 1.75] which are in the same positions [4, 5].

```py
>> and then listA_Var1 & listB_Var1 will become
listA_Var1 = [4.7, 1.2, 0.15, 0.99]
listB_Var1 = [0.54, 0.35, 1.19, 2.45]
```

Any ideas on an efficient way to implement that? From my experience using Matlab a lot, after comparing the two lists, I have a way to get the indexes that are not needed and then applying these indexes to the lists, what I get are the final lists listA_Var1 & listB_Var1.

Any ideas please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the `pandas` `numpy` aspect of this problem?

Comment: I am a bit unfamiliar with the "pandas" term (I will be honest), however, I thought numpy maybe as a Matlab style-wise solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Getting the Intersection**

There are many way to do this. For a detailed discussion see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432/how-to-find-list-intersection). As is suggested there, **if dublicates do not matter** (i.e. your lists either do not contain dublicates or they do but you do not care about them), you can, for example, use `set()` to get the shared values:

```
intersection_A_B = sorted(list(set(listA_ID) & set(listB_ID)))
```

[Alternatively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432/how-to-find-list-intersection/3697450#3697450), you can also turn just one of the lists into a set and then use the `intersection()` method, such as:

```
intersection_A_B = list(set(listA_ID).intersection(listB_ID))
```

In contrast, **if dublicates matter** or could pose an issue (say, both `listA_ID` and `listB_ID` feature a value twice and you want your intersection to preserve both listings of the value), instead of using `set()` or `intersection()`, you could [use list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33067553/16038459):

```
intersection_A_B = [x for x in listA_ID if x in listB_ID]
```

---

**2. Removing Values**

*Edit*: After getting the intersection (note that, now that I got what you were really after, the first step of the process refers to `intersection_A_B` instead of updating `listA_ID` and `listB_ID` because their original states are needed for the following operation), this should do the trick:

```
del_indices_A = [i for i, value in enumerate(listA_ID) if value not in intersection_A_B]
listA_Var1 = [listA_Var1[x] for x in range(len(listA_Var1)) if x not in del_indices_A]

del_indices_B = [i for i, value in enumerate(listB_ID) if value not in intersection_A_B]
listB_Var1 = [listB_Var1[x] for x in range(len(listB_Var1)) if x not in del_indices_B]
```

This first checks which indices in `listA_ID` and `listB_ID` corresponded to values not included in `intersection_A_B` and then excludes values corresponding to those indices in `listA_Var1` and `listB_Var2`.

Comment: This is an elegant solution using set +1.

Comment: Thank you very much @Georgy Kopshteyn. I did not make myself perfectly clear though. A1, A2... or B1, B2,... will not be strings, but numbers, floats to be exact. I just want to be able to extract the corresponding elements from listA_Var1 & listB_Var1, after the operation "listA_ID = listB_ID = list(set(listA_ID) & set(listB_ID))"

Comment: I would also recommed using sorted elements like `sorted(set(listA_ID).intersection(listB_ID))`

Comment: and I might have duplicate numbers, but the operation "listA_ID = listB_ID = list(set(listA_ID) & set(listB_ID))" seems to keep only the first duplicate it finds, and this suits my needs!

Comment: @V.Nikolaidis If you need to convert them to floats, simply use `float()` instead of the string formatting. E.g.: `listA_float = [float(x) for x in listA_ID]` would give you `[2.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 14.0]`. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: @V.Nikolaidis, if it fits your requirement, you should accept it as an answer.

Comment: Basically, as my final product, I want the numbers from listA_Var1 that correspond to the listA_ID, e.g.  listA_ID[1,3,4,5] which is [2,5,6,7], therefore I want the values from listA_Var1[1,3,4,5] that correspond to the values [4.7, 1.2, 0.15, 0.99]. (does it help a bit more in the clarification or am I thinking too much in Matlab style?)

Comment: @V.Nikolaidis So you want is to remove items from `listA_Var1` and `listB_Var1` whose indices are not included in the intersection of `listA_ID` and `listB_ID`? If this is the case, then I do not understand your example. 1. indices in python usually start counting from 0. So directly using `[2, 5, 6, 7]` would result in `listA_Var1 = [2.1, 0.99]`  (with indices 6 and 7 falling out of range). 2. Even when accounting for this by doing -1 for all indices, the result would be `listA_Var1 = [4.7, 0.15, 0.99]` (with index 7 being out of range). So how do you arrive at the result in your post?

Comment: Dear @GeorgyKopshteyn, thank you for supporting and keeping up with me. [2, 5, 6, 7] are not indices. These are the common ID values in both lists (listA_ID & listB_ID) that I want to keep. And therefore remove the values [1,3] from listA_ID and [8,10] from listB_ID at the positions [0,2] & [4,5] respectively. Then, I want to remove the values of the other 2 lists, listA_Var1 & listB_Var1, that correspond to the same indices [0,2] & [4,5] respectively.

Comment: @V.Nikolaidis Thank you for the update, I now have understood what you wanted to do. I have updated my answer accordingly, let me know whether this works for you. Note that, instead of updating `listA_ID` and `listB_ID` when performing in the first part, I now assign `sorted(list(set(listA_ID) & set(listB_ID)))` to `intersection_A_B` to preserve the original states of the lists for the second part of the operaton.

Comment: @GeorgyKopshteyn Thank you for your time and your fully working answer. I also managed to solve this problem with numpy. I will post my version shortly and if you have a few minutes, I would appreciate if you happen to know workaround is faster.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm going to explain step by step this approach:

**- Step 1:** We are going to looking for the intersection elements in both, `listA_ID` and `listB_ID`.

```
intersection_AB = set(listA_ID) & set(listB_ID)
```

**- Step 2:** Then, we do a [difference of sets](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_difference.asp). It's very important putting in the first place `set(listA_ID)`, because [the difference of sets is not commutative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOgVH.png).

```
# You can use difference() method alternatively:
# A_elements = list(set(listA_ID).difference(intersection_AB)) but personally I like the minus operator.

A_elements = list(set(listA_ID) - intersection_AB)
```

**- Step 3:** Then, We looking for the indexes based on the elements found in the previous step.

```
index_to_remove_list_A = [listA_ID.index(i) for i in A_elements]
```

Or you can use also (althoug less legible):

```
index_to_remove_list_A = [listA_ID.index(i) for i in list(set(listA_ID) - intersection_AB)]
```

**- Step 4:**
Delete the correct elements in the list.

```
for i in sorted(index_to_remove_list_A, reverse=True):
  del listA_Var1[i]

print(listA_Var1)
```

*Edit: Full code with both lists ...*

```
A_elements = list(set(listA_ID) - intersection_AB)
B_elements = list(set(listB_ID) - intersection_AB)

index_to_remove_list_A = [listA_ID.index(i) for i in A_elements]
index_to_remove_list_B = [listB_ID.index(i) for i in B_elements]

for i in sorted(index_to_remove_list_A, reverse=True):
  del listA_Var1[i]

for i in sorted(index_to_remove_list_B, reverse=True):
  del listB_Var1[i]


print(listA_Var1) # [4.7, 1.2, 0.15, 0.99]
print(listB_Var1) # [0.54, 0.35, 1.19, 2.45]
```

Comment: Your solution @CarMoreno is working fine as well with the difference() method and not the (-) sign. I can not understand why, because I have seen it elsewhere. Many Thanks for your time !!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I will post a working solution myself too, using numpy.

```py
intersection_A_B = sorted(list(set(listA_ID) & set(listB_ID)))

# Convert Lists to Arrays
np_listA_ID = np.asarray( listA_ID )
np_listB_ID = np.asarray( listB_ID )

# Comparison of two arrays
np_list_ID, listA_ind, listB_ind = np.intersect1d(np_listA_ID, np_listB_ID, assume_unique=False, return_indices=True)

# Keep only Items Needed    
np_listA_Var1 = np.asarray( listA_Var1 )
np_listB_Var1 = np.asarray( listB_Var1 )

# Covert Array to List again
listA_ID=listB_ID=np_list_ID.tolist()
listA_Var1 = np_listA_Var1[listA_ind].tolist()
listB_Var1 = np_listB_Var1[listB_ind].tolist()
```