# Check how many items from one list appear in another list

Tags: python, list

If I have 2 lists, for an example:

```
list_1 = ['a', 'A']
list_2 = ['a', 'A', 'A', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
```

How can I make a count to see how many times the items from `list_1` appear in `list_2`?

So in this case it should return `3`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find list intersection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697432/how-to-find-list-intersection)

Answer (score 1):

```
list_1 = ['a', 'A']
list_2 = ['a', 'A', 'A', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']

found = 0
for x in list_1:
    for y in list_2:
        if x == y:
            found += 1
print(found)
```

Comment: The complexity is bad though. If increases quadratically with the size of the inputs as you need to cross check all elements.

Answer (score 1):

An efficient O(n) method using a set as reference:

```
list_1 = ['a', 'A']
list_2 = ['a', 'A', 'A', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']

set_1 = set(list_1)

count = 0
for e in list_2:
    if e in set_1:
        counter += 1
```

Output: `3`

Answer (score 1):

A one liner:

```
sum([x == y for x in list_1 for y in list_2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, which could be beneficial in other cases, because the Counter()- object returns a dictionary with the already summed up elements

```
from collections import Counter

list_1 = ['a', 'A']
list_2 = ['a', 'A', 'A', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']

c = Counter(list_2)
print(sum([c[x] for x in list_1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `count` for lists:

```
print(list_2.count(list_1[0]) + list_2.count(list_1[1]))
```

or in a loop:

```
sum_ = 0
for i in range(len(list_1)):
    sum_ += list_2.count(list_1[i])
print(sum_)
```