# How to Compare Two ArrayList

Tags: c#

How to Compare Two ArrayList ?

```
ArrayList l1 = new ArrayList();
l1.Add(1);
l1.Add(2);
```

And I have another arrayList with same Value .Now I want to Compare both.If Both ArrayList contains same value then return True else False. Is There Any method without loop??

Comment: See here: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795882/quickest-way-to-compare-two-list>

Comment: FYI: You don't need use `ArrayList` anymore. It belongs the old days that C# doesn't have _Generics_. Use `List<int>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use `List` instead of `ArrayList` and then:

```
l1.SequenceEqual(l2);
```

I'm assuming `l2` is the name of the second list. Also, the values need to be in the same order in both lists for `SequenceEqual` to return true.

More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @BrijeshGandhi You have to convert l2 to an Array too. Otherwise you will get a runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code:

```
ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5});

ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList(new int[] {1,2,8});

for (int i=0; i<list1.Count && i<list2.Count; i++)

{

if (!Object.Equals(list1[i], list2[i]))

Console.WriteLine("Different value at index {0}.", i);

}

if (list1.Count > list2.Count)

Console.WriteLine("list1 has more elements than list2.");

if (list2.Count > list1.Count)

Console.WriteLine("list2 has more elements than list1.");

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET Framework 4.5, you can use *Structural Comparison*, as described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true). In your case, since `ArrayList` hasn't implemented `IStructuralEquatable` you have to fist create an array instance of your array lists and then use `IStructuralEquatable` as follows:

```
ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
list1.Add(1);
list2.Add(1);
if ((list1.ToArray() as IStructuralEquatable).Equals(list2.ToArray(), EqualityComparer<int>.Default))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Equal");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use this code:

```
ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList(new int[] {1,2});

ArrayList list2 = list1;

for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
   if(list1[i] == list2[i])
   {
       return true;
   }                
}

return false;
```

Comment: You obviously haven't tested this. It will return true if the very first two items of the lists are identical and stop checking right there.