# Comparing linkedlists c#

Tags: c#, list, linked-list, compare

I am having trouble comparing two linked lists, I have 2 lists for arguments sake `list1` contains `{1,2,3,4,5}` and `list2` contains `{1,3,4,5,6}`

I am not using `linkedlistnodes` for a start which is why I am asking the question here, I did try switch to notes but a lot of my other work would then have to be re-written to make it work which I don't really want to do.

Anyway here is my code thus far, I am trying to use 2 loops to cycle and compare each value. The problem is that it doesn't work in the way I intended as I didn't think that it will compare the first value of `list1` against all values in `list2` before moving on. It stumped me how to get this working or if I am even going about it in the right way.

```
bool c = false;
foreach (int s in list1) {
    foreach (int t in list2)
        if (s == t) {
            c = true;
            //The console write line in this part of the code is for testing
            Console.WriteLine("Both Lists Match  {0}, {1}", s, t);
            break;
        } else {
            c = false;
            //The console write line in this part of the code is for testing
            Console.WriteLine("Not a Match {0}, {1}", s, t);
        }
}

if (c == true) {
   Console.WriteLine("Both Lists Match");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Not a Match");
}
```

Comment: Do you know they are sorted when you begin?  Do you need to just determine whether they are equal? If not equal, do you want all the differences (found in a not b, found in b not a)?

Comment: i do as its the way i generate it but if there is a way to compare it regardless i would be much more in favour of that.

Comment: Can you use LINQ? `list1.SequenceEqual(list2)` should give you the right answer...

Comment: What are you trying to determine about these lists? Whether any of the elements in either are equal to its corresponding index's value in the other list?

Comment: You should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795882/quickest-way-to-compare-two-list to see if it is helpful for your situation.

Comment: ill have a look to see if im allowed to used linq but i am simply trying to test if all elements of list1 are in list2

Comment: Do you care about duplicates and order?

Comment: there wont be any duplicates

Comment: i guess the problem is you don't exit the for loops after setting c to false (in case there is no match), start with default true, if one fails, set c to false, and exit both for loops? also, maybe check before if the length of the list matches, if not it will never be equal...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You indicated that "i am simply trying to test if all elements of `list1` are in `list2`".

This can be solved using two nested loops where you compare the elements of the list, as you are trying with the code you have posted with your question, but there are a few problems with the posted code.

In terms of approach, the easiest way of thinking about this problem might be:

1. Assume `list2` contains all elements from `list1`
2. Compare each element `s` in `list1` with the elements `t` in `list2`
3. If `s != t`, for each `t` in `list2`, you know the assumption was not true and you can stop searching.

You could solve this (making minimal changes to your existing code), in the following manner:

```
    bool c = true; // assume each 's' is in 'list2'
    foreach (int s in list1)
    {
        bool contains_s = false; // 's' in 'list2' ?
        foreach (int t in list2)
        {
            if (s == t)
            {
                // found 's' in 'list2'.
                contains_s = true;
                //The console write line in this part of the code is for testing
                Console.WriteLine("Both Lists Match  {0}, {1}", s, t);
                break; // breaks out of the inner loop.
            }
        }
        if (!contains_s) // if 's' not found we are done.
        {
            c = false;
            break; // breaks out of the outer loop
        }
    }

    if (c == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Both Lists Match");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not a Match");
    }
```

If you are using LINQ, you can replace this with a much simpler statement, that basically does the same thing as the above loop.

```
var doesNotContainAllElements = list1.Any(s => !list2.Contains(s));
```

or

```
var containsAllElements = list1.All(s => list2.Contains(s));
```

Comment: BTW: why would someone use `O(n*n)` algorithm when it can be done in a linear time.

Comment: @EZ1, this does work for {1, 2} and {1, 2, 3}. Please remove your misleading comment about this not working. Also, regarding your second comment: given OPs question and posted code, it seemed reasonable to me to provide an answer that was in line with what he was already trying to do, as this would be easier to understand. You may not be familiar with the saying 'first make it work, if needed make it work faster'. Also, please post your O(n) solution, I would be most interested in how that is possible.

Comment: given `list1={1,2}` and `list2={1,2,3}` your code returns `Both Lists Match`. So what is misleading? (For `list2={1,2}` and `list1={1,2,3}` it returns `Not a Match` :)) ) **MySolution:** Read Jon Skeet's comment..

Comment: You may wish to read OPs replies on questions in the comments. OPs question (as indicated in the first line of my answer) appears to be *not* whether the lists are equal, but whether `list2` contains each of the items in `list1`.

Comment: As you said (`I hope I understood your question correctly`), it is only your assumption.

Comment: Yes, that is what his comment "ill have a look to see if im allowed to used linq but i am simply trying to test if all elements of list1 are in list2" implies. For that question, this answer is correct.

Comment: Put `list2` in a `HashSet` before doing the linq query for better performance.

Comment: @Magnus, I agree that in the general case (in terms of algorithmic complexity), this would be an improvement. In the question we are dealing with a list of ints, that we sequentially iterate over in a tight loop. If the list is not huge, then due to L1 cache locality and the predictable sequential access pattern this should perform pretty well.