# c# Comparing List<T> (s) using Linq

Tags: c#, collections

I want to compare two collections. I believe that I am doing it the long way (codewise). I want to find what numbers might be missing from a collection when compared to another collection. Order is unimportant.

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       List< int> x = new List<int>() { 1 };
       List< int> y = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };

        //find what numbers (if any) that x needs to  have in order to have  an identical list as y (order not important)

        List<int> missingNumbers = new List<int>();
        foreach (var number in y)
        {
            if (!x.Contains(number))
            {
                missingNumbers.Add(number);
            }
        }
        foreach (var missingNumber in missingNumbers)
        {
            x.Add(missingNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `y.Except(x)` ?

Comment: What about duplicates?

Comment: I want x to have the same items as y. order not important.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense - you can just do `x = new List<int>(); x.AddRange(y)` - surely there's more to it that just making x have the same items as y?

Comment: @PaulStanley That sounds like you just need `x = y.ToList()`, but I assume you want to keep values in x that are not in y, correct?

Comment: I want to know what numbers are missing. Then add them to x .Obviously in a complex object int could be a key but the process would be the same. I have two Lists to start with not one.

Comment: Just use Union extension method as I answered it.

Comment: Refer to the top answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795882/quickest-way-to-compare-two-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to directly combine the lists, a `.Union()` would certainly work. If you just want to find the values that are missing from one list to another, do an `.Except()`, e.g.

```
List<int> x = new List<int>() { 1 };
List<int> y = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var result = y.Except(x).ToList();
```

Where result will return `{ 2, 3 }`. If you then wanted to add `result` to `x`, simply do an `x.AddRange(result)`.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb358407(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method as follow:

```
// x will contain 1, 2, 3. 
// No ducplicate will be added 
// and the missing numbers 2 and 3 are added.
x = x.Union(y).ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question which was "find the numbers in x that are missing from y"

Comment: @Charleh the OP doesn't know what he wants `I want x to have the same items as y. order not important.`

Comment: "I want to know what numbers are missing. Then add them to x." by the OP

Comment: Yeah you were right in the first place, clarification by the OP always helps :)

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick:

```
x.AddRange(y.Where(num => !x.Contains(num)));
```

Comment: What's the point of the `ToList`?  Also there seems to be a missing `)`.

Comment: This won't remove duplicates