# Comparing two lists "List<Category>" where Category is my class

Tags: c#

I have to find out the difference between two lists of class `Category`.

My `Category` class has these properties:

```
 public class Category
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public bool IsQuantitative
    {
        get { return Products.Any(x => x.IsMultiPart); }
    }

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "difference" is a broad term.  What *specific* difference are you concerned with?  The order of the items?  The number of items?  The values of certain properties in each object?  Something else?

Comment: How do you *define* the difference between the two lists?  How do you define the difference between two instances of `Category` for that matter?  You have to define what it is you *want* to do before you or anyone else can actually do it.

Comment: if the value of any list item dis matches, it should point out me that specific item. Does that make sence

Comment: Great, so update your question to include that clarification.  The comments is not the place for substantive clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

I would sort the two lists by Id first. 
Then run through it and compare the Objects. 
This is a good Object Comparer:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/CompareNETObjects/

Here a little example:

```
            //Here you set the config like you want to have it compared
            ComparisonConfig comparisonConfig = new ComparisonConfig()
            {
                CompareChildren = true,
                CompareFields = true,
                CompareReadOnly = true,
                CompareProperties = true,
                MaxDifferences = 1,
                MaxByteArrayDifferences = 1
            };

            CompareLogic comparer = new CompareLogic() { Config = comparisonConfig };

            list1 = list1.OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
            list2 = list2.OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();


            for (int i =0;i> list1.count;i++)
            {
                //Here you get a bool if the two Objects are Equal
                bool areEqual = comparer.Compare(list1[i], list2[i]).AreEqual;

                //Here you get a List of Differences Objects. It contains Values like "expected and "actual" etc.
                var differences = comparer.Compare(list1[i], list2[i]).Differences;

                //Here you handle Differences etc.
            }
```

Comment: You could improve this answer by showing a brief example

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> var firstNotSecond = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
>
> var secondNotFirst = list2.Except(list1).ToList();

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795882/quickest-way-to-compare-two-list)