# LINQ - Compare List objects and List of strings

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have a list of objects (`List1`) and list of string  (`List2` - list of Names of the objects)

I need to get all objects from List1 if the object.Name does not exists in List2

How can write this `LINQ` C#.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quickest way to compare two List<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795882/quickest-way-to-compare-two-list). I realize this is `string` vs. `object`, but [Skeet's answer refers to that issue specifically in the comments as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795882/quickest-way-to-compare-two-list#comment60600663_12795900).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

var List1 = new List<Class1>();
var List2 = new List<string>();
var result = List1.Where(x=>!List2.Contains(x.Name)).ToList();
```

Or:

```
var result = List1.Where(x=>!List2.Any(n=>n==x.Name)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<List1Class> listClass = new List<List1Class>();

        listClass.Add(new List1Class { ObjectName = "obj1" });
        listClass.Add(new List1Class { ObjectName = "obj2" });
        listClass.Add(new List1Class { ObjectName = "obj3" });
        listClass.Add(new List1Class { ObjectName = "obj4" });

        List<string> listString = new List<string>();
        listString.Add("obj2");
        listString.Add("obj4");
        listString.Add("obj5");

        var filterlist = listClass.Where(l => !listString.Contains(l.ObjectName)).ToList();

    }
}
```

class List1Class
    {
        public string ObjectName { get; set; }

```
    //Add other property
}
```