# Unit testing two C# lists

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a method which takes in a list collection of objects. The idea is the method will check a specific field `CoverArt` in each of the objects passed into it and if the `CoverArt` property is null, an empty string, or an empty space, it will set it to a default value. If the `CoverArt` property is not null, empty string, or a white space, it just returns whatever string is in there already.

```
//checks a list of stories for cover art and sets cover art to a default if it is null
   public string CheckIfCoverArtIsNullForStoryList(List<Story> stories)
   {
    foreach (var story in stories)
    {
        if (story.CoverArt == null || story.CoverArt == "" || story.CoverArt == " ")
    {
    return story.CoverArt = "default-book.png";
   }
   return story.CoverArt;
}

            return "";
        }
```

What I'm trying to do is create a unit test that will test whether or not this method even works but I'm having difficult trying to compare two lists. What is wrong with my code?

```
[TestMethod]
        [Description("Tests list of stories for null cover art")]
        public void TestingStoryListCoverArtMethodWithValidInput()
        {
            List<Story> StoryListActual = new List<Story>()
            {
                new Story()
                {
                    CoverArt = "Lord of the Rings.png"
                },
                new Story()
                {
                    CoverArt = "Johnny Appleseed.jpeg"
                },
                new Story()
                {
                    CoverArt = "The Great Gatsby.jpg"
                },
                new Story()
                {
                    CoverArt = "Happy Gilmore.gif"
                }
            };

            List<Story> CoverArtExpected = new List<Story>()
            {
                new Story()
                {
                    CoverArt = "Lord of the Rings.png"
                },
                new Story()
                {
                    CoverArt = "Johnny Appleseed.jpeg"
                },
                new Story()
                {
                    CoverArt = "The Great Gatsby.jpg"
                },
                new Story()
                {
                    CoverArt = "Happy Gilmore.gif"
                }
            };

            helper.CheckIfCoverArtIsNullForStoryList(StoryListActual);

            for (var i = 0; i < StoryListActual.Count; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < CoverArtExpected.Count; j++)
                {
                    Assert.AreEqual(StoryListActual[i].CoverArt, CoverArtExpected[j].CoverArt);
                }
            }
        }
```

My unit testing is failing with this message.

[image]

Comment: Why do you expect every StoryListActual item to be the same as all CoverArtExpected? Just remove the second for loop

Comment: because I'm trying to test valid inputs - that none of them should return "default-pic" or whatever. Then I'll try and test when some are empty, null, etc... if I remove the second for loop, how would I get access to each individual member of the second list as they cycle through?

Comment: Your current code says: "every item in StoryListActual is equal to every item in CovertArtExpected." It says "Lord of the Rings.png is equal to Lord of the Rings.png and to Johnny Appleseed.jpeg"

Comment: You can use [CollectionAssert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms243763.aspx) to compare lists.

Comment: Right. I need it to assert that lord of the rings equals lord of the rings, johnny Appleseed jpeg equals Johnny Appleseed jpeg... in another test I’ll put in an empty string and assert that it equal default-pic

Comment: So...? Just use `Assert.AreEqual(StoryListActual[i].CoverArt, CoverArtExpected[i].CoverArt);`? (notice it's `i` in both cases)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795882/quickest-way-to-compare-two-list

Comment: Unrelated tip: [string.IsNullOrWhitespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netframework-4.7.2) method

Comment: @Richardissimo thanks. I'm aware of it. I'm not taking in a string as a parameter, though, but I could rework the method to do that.

Comment: @J.G.Sable No need to change the parameter I'm suggesting that you do `string.IsNullOrWhitespace(story.CoverArt)`.