# C# for comparing two lists that may contain null values

Tags: c#, excel

I am comparing two excel sheets using C#.

I have assigned the sheets to datatables and I hope to compare the values in each cell. I have converted the datatables to lists and I'm iterating through them comparing them. How do I avoid a NullReferenceException if one of the values contains a null?

I am hitting a NullReferenceException at this point in the code:

```
    if (lst1[i].ToString() != lst2[j].ToString())
```

Is there a way to guard against nulls here or do I need to handle null values earlier in the code?

Thanks

Comment: Please add  ?.ToString()

Comment: Could you try this aproach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795882/quickest-way-to-compare-two-generic-lists-for-differences?

Comment: `i` and `j` look confusing. Are you comparing an item from first list to every item in your second list?

Answer (score 1):

One good way to do this is to ask if the value is null **before** call `.ToString()`.

So, would be like:

`if (lst1[i] != null && lst2[j] != null && lst1[i].ToString() != lst2[j].ToString())`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (lst1[i]?.ToString() != lst2[j]?.ToString())
```

[More info on the ?. operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

Answer (score 1):

Just test for null before dereferencing lst1[i] and lst2[j]

```
if(lst1[i] is not null and lst2[j] is not null)
{
     if (lst1[i].ToString() != lst2[j].ToString())
     {
         ...
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

- if both items are null then they are equal;
- if both items are not null and their string representation are equal then they are equal;
- in any other case they are not equal;

you can make comparison of your lists more readable With following LINQ query.

```
var query = list1
    .Zip(list2, (a, b) => new { a, b })
    .Any(m => !((m.a == null && m.b == null) || (m.a != null && m.b != null && m.a.ToString() == m.b.ToString())));

if (query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Lists are not equal.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Lists are equal.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing `ToString()` it looks like both lists are typed as objects. Since they're coming from Excel they're presumably all either strings or simple value types.

In that case you can do

```cs
if(lst1.SequenceEquals(lst2))
```

That compares each item in both lists and ensure that they're equal. It accounts for nulls. You wouldn't need to compare each item one at a time. This compares the entire list. I'd write unit tests to make sure it doesn't throw any curves.

If for some reason you wanted to do a text-based comparison ("2" == 2) then you could create a comparer like this:

```cs
public class ObjectTextComparer : IEqualityComparer<object>
{
    public bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        return x?.ToString() == y?.ToString();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object obj)
    {
        return obj?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
    }
}
```

and then this would return true:

```cs
var x = new object[] { "x", 2, null, "y" };
var y = new object[] { "x", "2", null, "y" };
var comparer = new ObjectTextComparer();
var listsAreEqual = x.SequenceEqual(y, comparer);
```

That second option is a can of worms, though, if the values in one list are stored in Excel as text and the other ones as numbers or dates.

For example if one list contains a date and the other list contains the same date stored as text, the comparer is going to convert the first one to a string, but it might not be formatted the same way as the other one stored as text, and the two strings won't match.