# How to check of the existence of any value in the list in python

Tags: python, list

I have the list like

```
l = ['dd','rr','abcde']

l2 = ['ddf','fdfd','123']
```

I want one function which return true if any of the value from `l` exist in `l2`.

Now that can be partial matching as well. i mean that string should present in `l2`

EDIT:

The output should be either true of false

Like in my example it should return true because `dd` is matching with `ddf`

Comment: What would be the expected output for your example? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: This has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches and is quite a good solution

Comment: @cyroxx the output should be either true or false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This returns `True` if any value from `l` is a substring of any value in `l2`:

```
any(l_value in l2_value for l_value in l for l2_value in l2)
```

Comment: By last sentence i mean that your function should give true as output as `dd` in l1 is matching with `ddf`

Answer (score 1):

Nested loops:

```
print any(sub in full for sub in l for full in l2)
```

Efficient nested loops

```
from itertools import product
print any(sub in full for sub, full in product(l, l2))
```

No loops:

```
import re
print re.match('|'.join(l), ' '.join(l2))
```

Comment: `product` is not more efficient. All this tuple creation and unpacking adds up.

Comment: @PavelAnossov: efficient != fast

Answer (score 0):

```
def match():
   for e in l:
      for e2 in l2:
          if e in e2:
              return True
   else:
       return False
```

This will include the partial matches.

**UPDATE:**
Using list comprehension:

```
[re.search(x,",".join(l2)) for x in l if re.search(x,",".join(l2)) is not None] and 'True' or 'False'
```