# loop through two multidimensional arrays

Tags: python

I have two multiD lists

```
 list one [["hello","how", "are", "you"]] and
 list two [["ss", "gg", "ff"]]
```

I want to compare EACH of the rows in list one with all of the rows values in list two.

**Example**

```
If list one has 2 rows with arrays list[2][values]
and list two has 3 rows with arrays list[3][values]
then

list one [0][all values] compare with
     list two[0][values],
     list two[1][values],
     list two[2][values], and
     list two[3][values].
Then take row two of list one and compare it with
     all rows in list two again
     and so on.
```

how could that be done?

Comment: I can't understand your explanation. Can you post a sample input and output?

Comment: did you try to write any code so far? SO is not a site to ask others to do stuff on your behalf, but a place where you can get *help*

Comment: well. I cannot do it. that's why I ask

Answer (score 3):

Basically, it's nested for loop. You can use list comprehension to do that.

```
matches = [(A.index(a),B.index(b)) for a in A for b in B if len(set(a).intersection(set(b)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is pseudo-code, I'll respond the same way. ;-)

```
for all rows in list1:
    for all rows in list2:
        %comparison of rows..
        matches = set(current row of list1) & set(current row of list2)
```

Basically, [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches) should cover your problem.
Possibly, there is a more efficient way to the solution. I'm a beginner with python myself.

Answer (score 0):

So given

```
A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
B = [[11,12,13],[14,15,16],[17,18,19]]
```

Is this what you want?

```
for a_row in A:
  for b_row_i in xrange(len(B)):
    print 'compare', a_row, B[b_row_i]
```