# Compare two lists, dictionaries in easy way

Tags: python, nose

How to compare two lists or dictionaries in easy way,

eg.

```
assert orig_list == new_list
```

If I want to check two lists in python nose tests,

Is there any built-in function can let me use?

Does compare two lists is a bad practice when doing testing ?(because I've never see it)

If there is no built-in, plugin in nose, is there any handy package can do it for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [assertListEqual(a, b)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertListEqual) and [assertDictEqual(a, b)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertDictEqual) from the `unittest` library.

Answer (score 1):

set is used to do that between two lists/dicts!

```
set(orig_list) & set(new_list)
```

Comment: Yes, doing an `assert_equals(set(orig_list), set(new_list))` prints nice output. You just have to be careful that sometimes you might not want set comparison (when duplicates occur).

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. Manually checking every element for equality.

```
(len(a) == len(b)) and  (all(ai == bi for ai,bi in zip(a,b)))
```