# Python: How to Compare Two Lists

Tags: python

What would be the fastest to iterate list `x` to check if any of its characters are listed in `y`?

```
x=['cat','dog','fish']
y=['a','b','b']
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches

Comment: @sfletche I don't think that is a duplicate, that is comparing two strings to see if they are the same, this is checking **if a character is *in* a string**

Comment: thanks @aj8uppal.  you're right.  sorry about that.

Comment: Remember to accept an answer which helped you (the green tick next to the answer, it gives you +2 reputation :))

Comment: Please make some effort to help people understand the question, otherwise you are wasting everybody's time who are trying to help you. Close voting the question as it is not clear.

Comment: @David, when someone suggests an edit, it is your job to approve/disapprove it, **not to take those edits and mark it as your own.**

Comment: achieve the solution with best possible way, however remember to vote for the answers you find right.

Comment: What is a reason for downvote? Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `y` to a set and then iterate over `x` to see if any of `y` is in it, like this

```
print any(any(item in word for word in x) for item in set(y))
# True
```

[`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) short-circuits immediately after finding a match, so this would be very efficient.

Apart from that we can convert both of them to sets, and then check if they are disjoint sets, like this

```
print not {char for word in x for char in word}.isdisjoint(set(y))
# True
```

[`isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint) also short-circuits if it determines that both the sets are not disjoint sets.

Comment: I'm liking this one too! Thanks!

Comment: @Sputnix Can you please edit the question include a sample output, so that the future readers will also get benefited? As it is, question is not clear.

Comment: +1 for the short circiuting `isdisjoint`.  I didn't know about that one.

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension:

```
>>> x=['cat','dog','fish']
>>> y=['a','b','b']
>>> [char in word for char in y for word in x]
[True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
>>>
```

This prints the above output for all the characters and words: `True` because `'a'` is in `'cat'`, and `False` for the rest, because nothing else exists.

Here is an example that is easier to read:

```
>>> x = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish']
>>> y = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> [(word, char, char in word) for char in y for word in x]
[('cat', 'a', True), ('dog', 'a', False), ('fish', 'a', False), ('cat', 'b', False), ('dog', 'b', False), ('fish', 'b', False), ('cat', 'c', True), ('dog', 'c', False), ('fish', 'c', False)]
>>> ["It is %s that %s is in %s" %(str(char in word), char, word) for char in y for word in x]
['It is True that a is in cat', 'It is False that a is in dog', 'It is False that a is in fish', 'It is False that b is in cat', 'It is False that b is in dog', 'It is False that b is in fish', 'It is True that c is in cat', 'It is False that c is in dog', 'It is False that c is in fish']
>>>
```

Answering your comment, yes there is way:

```
>>> x = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish']
>>> y = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> myList = []
>>> [myList.append(word) for word in x for char in y if char in word]
[None, None]
>>> myList
['cat', 'cat']
>>> list(set(myList))
['cat']
>>>
```

The reason why the list comprehension prints `[None, None]` is because the built-in method `append()` doesn't return anything, hence the `None`.

Comment: Remember to accept an answer which helped you (the green tick next to the answer, it gives you +2 reputation :))

Comment: Is there any CPU utilization 'release' versus nested 'for word in x: for char in y: if char in word: myList.append(word)' approach?

Answer (score 0):

why isn't this enough for comparison?

```
>>> x=['cat','dog','fish']
>>> y=['a','b','b']
>>> x == y
False
>>> b = ['a','b', 'b']
>>> x == b
False
>>> y == b
True
```