# Find similar items in list of lists using Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to do something similar to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches), but using lists of lists. Doing the following, however, gives me a TypeError.

```
list1 = [[a,a], [b,b], [c,c]]
list2 = [[c,c], [d,d], [e,e]]

same = set(list1) & set(list2)
```

I'm also trying to find:

```
different = not set(list1) & set(list2)
```

Comment: use tuples for the pairs instead of lists. The elements of a set have to be hashable

Comment: As a general rule, when you get a ``TypeError`` (or any error) it is helpful to post the error text along with your question. In this case the problem was easy to deduce, but it really is quite helpful to answerers on more complex problems. The errors generally tell you exactly what went wrong, once you know how to read them.

Comment: for `different` use `set(list1 + list2) - same` when `list1` and `list2` are a list of tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists are not hashable types, so they can't be put into sets, but tuples can. You can convert a list to a tuple with `tuple(mylist)`. The following code assumes that a,b,c,d and e are hashable types.

```
list1 = [(a,a), (b,b), (c,c)]
list2 = [(c,c), (d,d), (e,e)]

same = set(list1) & set(list2)
```

Comment: i ended up converting my list of lists to list of tuples using the map function. same = set(map(tuple, list1)) & set(map(tuple, list2))

Answer (score 0):

It would be more readable and more understandable if you just used list comprehension like so ..

```
def seperate(*ls):
   sim, diff = []
   for l in ls:
       sim.extend([ x for x in l if x not in sim ])
       diff.extend([ x for x in l if x not in sim ])
   return sim, diff
```