# python: compare two lists and return matches in order

Tags: python, list, set

I have two lists of unequal length and I would like to compare and pull matched values in the order from the first list, so a in this example.

```
a = ['a','s','d','f']
b = ['e','d','y','a','t','v']
```

expected output:

```
['a','d']
```

I was doing it like this but I forgot that set doesnt retain the order! how can I edit my code below to retain the order.

```
 set(a).intersection(b)
```

Linked to this [How can I compare two lists in python and return matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches)

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: How is the order defined? – _

Comment: The order found in "a"

Comment: which list will you give priority for order???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert `b` to a set and then loop over `a`'s items and check if they exist in that set:

```
>>> s = set(b)
>>> [x for x in a if x in s]
['a', 'd']
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to use set:

```
>>> a = ['a','s','d','f']
>>> b = ['e','d','y','a','t','v']
>>> sorted(set(a) & set(b), key=a.index) # here sorting is done on the index of a
['a', 'd']
```

Comment: What if  `a = ['a','s','d','a']`?

Comment: I would expect `['a', 'd', 'a']` but the question might be academic.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ['a','s','d','f']
b = ['e','d','y','a','t','v']
st_b = set(b)
print([ele for ele in a if ele in st_b])
['a', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['a','s','d','f']
b = ['e','d','y','a','t','v']
matches=[]
for item_a in a:
    for item_b in b:
        if item_a == item_b:
            matches.append(item_a)
print(matches)
```